# Why is "None" printed after my function's output?

Tags: python, function

I tried writing this code:

```
def smaller(x, y):
    if x > y:
        print(y) 
    else:
        print(x) 

print(smaller(2, 3))
```

I got this result:

```
>>>
2
None
```

Where did the `None` come from? What does it mean?

---

#### See also

<sub>The accepted answer explains the importance of `return`ing a value from the function, rather than `print`ing it. For more information, see [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285).</sub>

<sub>To understand the `None` result itself, see [What is a 'NoneType' object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object).</sub>

<sub>If you are `print`ing inside the function in order to see multiple values, it may be better to instead *collect* those values so that they can be printed by the calling code. For details, see [How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a loop? Can I put them in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564414/).</sub>

Comment: Related: [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750136/7851470)

Comment: you forgot to return a value in your function so the intrepretor returned none

Comment: @Georgy I've edited the canonical for that link into the question. I've been doing a fair bit of work cleaning up canonicals for Python questions lately.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's the return value of the function, which you print out. If there is no return statement (or [just a `return` without an argument](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#return)), an implicit `return None` is added to the end of a function.

You probably want to return the values in the function instead of printing them:

```
def jiskya(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return y
    else:
        return x

print(jiskya(2, 3))
```

Comment: Is there a place where it is specified, that "an implicit `return None` is added"?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I could not find any statement to that effect in [the Python reference](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/index.html), but [here is the comment (and code) adding the `return None` in cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23cee80cfade1a9019c52b3a17d8e5c1b5db17e2/Python/compile.c#L5501-L5510).

Comment: if I wanted to be explicit, could I end the function with `return None` ?

Comment: @PatrickT In the example of the question that makes no sense, but yes, if you want your function to return `None` then `return None` is great, and probably clearer than just a bare `return`.

Comment: @phihag: I didn't find one in the reference, but [the official tutorial on defining functions](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) says: "The `return` statement returns with a value from a function. `return` without an expression argument returns `None`. Falling off the end of a function also returns `None`."

Answer (score 18):

Ok, to start off when you do this:

```
print(jiskya(2, 3))
```

You getting something pretty much equivalent to this:

```
print(print(2))
```

So, what is going on? The `print(2)` is printing out 2, and returns `None` which is printed by the outer call. Straightforward enough.

Now look at this:

```
def hello():
    return 2
```

If you do:

```
print(hello())
```

You get 2 because if you print out a function you get whatever the `return` value is. (The `return` value is denoted by the `return someVariable`.

Now even though `print` doesn't have parenthesis like most functions, it is a function just a little special in that respect. What does print return? Nothing. So when you `print print someVariable`, you will get `None` as the second part because the return value of print is `None`.

So as others have stated:

```
def jiskya(x, y):
    if x > y:
        print(y)
    else:
        print(x)
```

Should be re-written:

```
def jiskya(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return y
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: What if the print argument is in a while loop? If I replace "print" with "return", then I can only get one value printed instead of the full iteration.

Answer (score 5):

> Where did the 'None' come from?

The function.

> And what is it?

It's what the function returned.

In Python, every function returns something. It could "be multiple things" using a tuple, or it could "be nothing" using `None`, but it must return something. This is how we deal with the fact that there is no way to specify a return type (which would make no sense since you don't specify types for anything else). When interpreted as a string for printing, `None` is replaced with the string "None".

`None` is a special object that is supposed to represent the absence of any real thing. Its type is `NoneType` (it is an instance of that class). Whenever you don't explicitly return anything, you implicitly return None.

You wrote the function to print one of the two values `x` or `y`, but not to return anything. So `None` was returned. Then you asked Python to print the result of calling the function. So it called the function (printing one of the values), then printed the return value, which was `None`, as the text "None".

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two prints, the first one in the corpus of your function and the second one is printing the result of the function, which as actually None.

You should rather do something like this:

```
def yourfunction(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return y
    else:
        return x
```

Then,

```
>>> print yourfunction(2, 3)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya, basically you are using print statements in your function as a way to return information. You shouldn't do this. Print is NOT the same as a return statement. If you simply want your function to give your answer without the none, just type jiskya(2, 3) instead. You will see what the function throws out because you have print statements in the function. If instead you typed "return" in your function, it wouldn't give you anything without the "print" preceding the function call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you wrote `print jiskya(2,3)`. You're passing the return value of `jiskya` to the `print` function. `jiskya` itself prints `x` or `y`, which is why you see the 2. But then the `print` in the `print jiskya(2, 3)` statement itself executes with no argument.

To the interpreter, this is a simplification of what happens:

```
print jiskya(2,3)
>> Executing jiskya with arguments 2, 3
>> jiskya evaulates `print x`
>> 2 is printed
>> Function jiskya exits with no return value
print None
>> None is printed
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider following examples:

**Function without return statement**

Print() function type is none type..

```
def test1():

    print("code...!!!")

type(test1())

Output: code...!!!
        NoneType
```

**Function with return statement**

Returning variable 'a' which holds print() function, that's why type() returns data type of print function which is NoneType, not the data type of what's inside the print funcion:

```
def test1():

    a= print("code...!!!")
    
    return a

type(test1())


Output: code...!!!
        NoneType
```

Here function returning data type of variable 'a' which holds a string in it.

```
def test1():

    a = "First code...!!!"
    
    return a

type(test1())


Output: str
```