# What is a 'NoneType' object?

Tags: python, null, nonetype

I'm getting this error when I run my python script:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

I'm pretty sure the 'str' means string, but I dont know what a 'NoneType' object is. My script craps out on the second line, I know the first one works because the commands from that line are in my asa as I would expect. At first I thought it may be because I'm using variables and user input inside send_command.

Everything in 'CAPS' are variables, everything in 'lower case' is input from 'parser.add_option' options.

I'm using pexpect, and optparse

```
send_command(child, SNMPGROUPCMD + group + V3PRIVCMD)
send_command(child, SNMPSRVUSRCMD + snmpuser + group + V3AUTHCMD + snmphmac + snmpauth + PRIVCMD + snmpencrypt + snmppriv)
```

Comment: We need to see more code and the input - NoneTyoe means that one of the variables has not been set

Comment: `NoneType` is the type of the singleton value `None`. One of your values is not a string.

Comment: Quick&Dirty: put each term to concatenate in `str()` str(SNMPSRVUSRCMD) + str(snmpuser) + ...

Comment: @PeterMmm That's a terrible idea -- the problem will just manifest itself (perhaps worse) further down the line. It would be better to figure out *why* one of the variables is None to begin with.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`NoneType` is the type for the `None` object, which is an object that indicates *no value*. `None` is the return value of functions that "don't return anything". It is also a common default return value for functions that search for something and may or may not find it; for example, it's returned by `re.search` when the regex doesn't match, or `dict.get` when the key has no entry in the dict. You cannot add `None` to strings or other objects.

One of your variables is `None`, not a string. Maybe you forgot to `return` in one of your functions, or maybe the user didn't provide a command-line option and `optparse` gave you `None` for that option's value. When you try to add `None` to a string, you get that exception:

```
send_command(child, SNMPGROUPCMD + group + V3PRIVCMD)
```

One of `group` or `SNMPGROUPCMD` or `V3PRIVCMD` has `None` as its value.

Comment: Thanks!! You where correct, one of my user input options was not taking for some reason. I added this as a "name" vs an option and boom, it worked. Now I just have to find out why this is not taking properly as an option, all the other options are working fine.

Comment: "Not set" is a bit vague...if a variable is not defined and you try to perform some operation with it, you should get a `NameError`. It could also be set, but equal to `None` ("set to nothing" = "not set"?), then you might get some `TypeError`.

Comment: Basically (for the C/Java folks here) none = null

Answer (score 39):

For the sake of defensive programming, objects should be checked against nullity before using.

```
if obj is None:
```

or

```
if obj is not None:
```

Comment: "is" should only be used if you need it.  The best defensive programming is tests, lots of tests.

Comment: Defensive programming is one of the most evil things. If you find an error like that, this means you made a mistake programming. Stuff like "checking for null before use" only hides some serious error. You should let the exception be thrown. And don't make programmers throw some custom exception, it is really cumbersome. Let the natural error be thrown. In fact, defensive programming is a symptom that you should be using another language.

Comment: I query the database via sqlAlchemy. There's no result. Returned object is None. Which means no result. There is no error. You check if a result is none, if not, you use the result object. Nothing evil about it. The most evil thing about programming is dogmatism.

Answer (score 29):

[`NoneType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType) is simply the type of the [`None`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) singleton:

```
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

From the latter link above:

> **`None`**
>
> The sole value of the type `NoneType`. `None` is frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a function. Assignments to `None` are illegal and raise a `SyntaxError`.

In your case, it looks like one of the items you are trying to concatenate is `None`, hence your error.

Comment: Except that the name `NoneType` exists only in [some versions of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68283326/2810305).

Comment: @LutzPrechelt would the versions of python that don't contain NoneType give the error: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects ?

Comment: @N8tron: Yes. There the string 'NoneType' is only some wording an error message, not the builtin name of an object the interpreter would (need to) recognize.

Answer (score 18):

It means you're trying to concatenate a string with something that is `None`.

None is the "null" of Python, and `NoneType` is its type.

This code will raise the same kind of error:

```
>>> bar = "something"
>>> foo = None
>>> print foo + bar
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Answer (score 11):

### In Python

- NoneType is the type of the `None` object.
- There is only one such object.
  Therefore, "*a* None object" and "*the* None object" and
  "None" are three equivalent ways of saying the same thing.
- Since all Nones are identical and not only equal,
  you should prefer `x is None` over `x == None` in your code.
- You will get `None` in many places in regular Python
  code as pointed out by the accepted answer.
- You will also get `None` in your own code when you
  use the function result of a function that does not end with
  `return myvalue` or the like.

Representation:

- There is a type `NoneType` in some but not all versions of Python,
  see below.
- When you execute `print(type(None))`, you will get
  `<type 'NoneType'>`.
  This is produced by the `__repr__` method of `NoneType`.
  See the [documentation of `repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)
  and that of
  [magic functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)
  (or "dunder functions" for the *d*ouble *under*scores in their names) in general.

### In Python 2.7

- `NoneType` is a type defined in the
  [standard library module `types`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html)

### In Python 3.0 to 3.9

- NoneType has been
  [removed](https://bugs.python.org/issue19438)
  from
  [module `types`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/types.html),
  presumably because there is only a single value of this type.
- It effectively exists nevertheless, it only has no built-in name:
  You can access NoneType by writing `type(None)`.
- If you want `NoneType` back, just define
  `NoneType = type(None)`.

### In Python 3.10+

- `NoneType` is again a type defined in the
  [standard library module `types`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html),
  introduced in order to
  [help type checkers do their work](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706609

Answer (score 4):

In Python, to represent the absence of a value, you can use the `None` value `types.NoneType.None`

Comment: For Python 3, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706609/where-is-the-nonetype-located-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 2):

In the error message, instead of telling you that you can't concatenate two objects by showing their values (a string and `None` in this example), the Python interpreter tells you this by showing the types of the objects that you tried to concatenate. The type of every string is `str` while the type of the single `None` instance is called `NoneType`.

You normally do not need to concern yourself with `NoneType`, but in this example it is necessary to know that `type(None) == NoneType`.

Comment: I have a very similar problem and trying to detect if the object is NoneType, your affirmation doesn't work for me: 
`>>> type(key) 
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(key) == NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined`

Comment: @RuBiCK `NoneType` is not defined anywhere (that I am aware of). If you want to check whether a value is `None`, just use `key is None` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python). Otherwise you could use `type(key) == type(None)` to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your error's occurring due to something like this:
`>>> None + "hello world"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`
>>>

Python's *None* object is roughly equivalent to *null*, *nil*, etc. in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting type `None` for an object, make sure you're returning in the method. For example:

```
class Node:
    # node definition
```

then,

```
def some_funct():
    # some code
    node = Node(self, self.head)
    self.head = node
```

if you do not return anything from `some_func()`, the return type will be `NoneType` because it did not return anything.

Instead, if you return the node itself, which is a `Node` object, it will return the `Node-object` type.

```
def some_func(self):
    node = Node(self, self.head)
    self.head = node
    return node
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the variables has not been given any value, thus it is a NoneType. You'll have to look into why this is, it's probably a simple logic error on your part.

Answer (score 0):

`NoneType` is the type of `None`.

See the Python 2 docs here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType

Answer (score 0):

It's returned when you have for instance `print` as your last statement in a function instead of `return`:

```
def add(a, b):
    print(a+ b)

x = add(5,5)
print(x)
print(type(x))

y = x + 545
print(y)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
<class 'NoneType'>

```
def add(a, b):
    return (a+ b)

x = add(5,5)
print(x)
print(type(x))

10
<class 'int'>
555
```

Answer (score 0):

NoneType is type of None. Basically, The NoneType occurs for multiple reasons,

- Firstly when you have a function and a condition inside (for instance), it will return None if that condition is not met.
  Ex:-
  `def dummy(x, y):  if x > y: return x res = dummy(10, 20) print(res) # Will give None as the condition doesn't meet.`

To solve this return the function with 0, I.e return 0, the function will end with 0 instead of None if the condition is not satisfied.

- Secondly, When you explicitly assign a variable to a built-in method, which doesn't return any value but None.
  my_list = [1,2,3]
  my_list = my_list.sort()
  print(my_list) #None sort() mutate the DS but returns nothing if you print it.
  Or
  lis = None
  re = lis.something())
  print(re) # returns attribute error NonType object has no attribute something