# Where is the NoneType located?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, nonetype

In Python 3, I would like to check whether `value` is either string or `None`.

One way to do this is

```
assert type(value) in { str, NoneType }
```

But where is `NoneType` located in Python?

Without any import, using `NoneType` produces `NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined`.

Comment: You should also use `isinstance`.  It can take a tuple of types to check.  `isinstance(value, (str, type(None)))`

Comment: If this is not for unit testing, one could argue that you usually shouldn't type check at all.

Comment: @rmartinjak: some programmers still like to validate their coding assumptions with an `assert` statement. The support is there. *I* wouldn't use assertions and would use unit testing too, but if you are using `assert` anyway..

Comment: Sorry if my question was put wrong, I know about `isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple)`, I just wanted to focus on the problem of `NoneType`'s location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`types.NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html#types.NoneType) is being reintroduced in Python 3.10.

> [*What’s New In Python 3.10*](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-10)
>
> *Improved Modules*
>
> [*types*](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#types)
>
> Reintroduced the `types.EllipsisType`, `types.NoneType` and `types.NotImplementedType` classes, providing a new set of types readily interpretable by type checkers. (Contributed by Bas van Beek in [bpo-41810](https://bugs.python.org/issue41810).)

The discussion about the change was motivated by a need for `types.EllipsisType`, leading to `types.NoneType` also being [added for consistency](https://bugs.python.org/issue41810#msg377250).

Answer (score 54):

You can use `type(None)` to get the type object, but you want to use `isinstance()` here, not `type() in {...}`:

```
assert isinstance(value, (str, type(None)))
```

The `NoneType` object is not otherwise exposed anywhere in Python versions [older than 3.10](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85976)<sup>*</sup>.

I'd not use type checking for that at all really, I'd use:

```
assert value is None or isinstance(value, str)
```

as `None` is a singleton (very much on purpose) and `NoneType` explicitly forbids subclassing anyway:

```
>>> type(None)() is None
True
>>> class NoneSubclass(type(None)):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type 'NoneType' is not an acceptable base type
```

---

<sup>*</sup> As of Python 3.10, you could use [`types.NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.NoneType), to be consistent with the [other singleton types being added to the `types` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85976).

Answer (score 0):

Please use `type(None)`. You can use python shell to check like in the below function in which I use `type(None)` in order to change from `None` to `NoneType`.

```
def to_unicode(value):
'''change value to unicode'''
try:
    if isinstance(value, (str,type(None))):
        return value
    if not isinstance(value, bytes):
        raise TypeError("Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got %r" % type(value))
    return value.decode("utf-8")
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return repr(value)
```