# Type hinting Callable with no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, nonetype

I want to use type hinting for a function with no parameters

```py
from typing import Callable

def no_parameters_returns_int() -> int:
    return 7

def get_int_returns_int(a: int) -> int:
    return a
    
def call_function(next_method: Callable[[], int]):
    print(next_method())

call_function(no_parameters_returns_int)  # no indication of error from IDE expected
call_function(get_int_returns_int)        # expected an indication of error from IDE
```

I expected PyCharm to mark the line when I pass a function that does take parameters.
Also tried `Callabale[[None], int]` and `Callabale[[...], int]`. However the first one hinting the passed function to receive a `None` type argument, second one hinting the passed function to receive at least one argument.

Is it possible to hint that the passed function receives no arguments?

Comment: MyPy detects it correctly: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=fdaee2f85e8d21575885b86a7a63600b

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I switched to Callable[..., int] and got no errors from hinting, however I expected an error at runtime

Comment: What do you mean at runtime? Python doesn't type check at runtime, I assumed you were asking about PyCharm's failure to warn.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant that when python interpreter executes the line hof(one_arg) it should result in an error. However I opened your code on mypy and changed Callable[[], int] to Callable[..., int] and now there are no errors. Does mypy-play just tests type checking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to hint that the passed function receives no arguments?

The correct way to type hint a `Callable` without arguments is stated in:

> [*"Fundamental building blocks"*, PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks)
>
> `Callable[[t1, t2, ..., tn], tr]`. A function with positional argument types `t1` etc., and return type `tr`. **The argument list may be empty n==0**.

An explicit example is given in:

> [*"Covariance and Contravariance"*, PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance)
>
> ```py
> - Callable[[], int] is a subtype of Callable[[], float].
> - Callable[[], Manager] is a subtype of Callable[[], Employee].
> ```

And also in:

> [*"Callable"*, PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable)
>
> ```py
> from typing import Callable
>
> def feeder(get_next_item: Callable[[], str]) -> None:
>    # Body
> ```

The built-in name `None` should be distinguished from the **type *None*** (the first is used to access the second):

> [*3.2. The standard type hierarchy*, Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)
>
> None
>
> - **This type** has a single value. There is **a single object** with this value. This **object is accessed through the built-in name `None`**.

The syntax and meaning of the built-in name `None` used as a type hint is a special case:

> [*"Using None"*, PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#using-none)
>
> When used in a type hint, the expression `None` is considered equivalent to `type(None)`.

Considering the above, it's less of a surprise the following two ways -of trying to write a `Callable` type hint of a function without arguments- are wrong:

```py
Callable[[None], tr]
Callable[[type(None)], tr]
```

The Ellipsis in a `Callable` type hint simply means:

> [*"Callable"*, PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable)
>
> Note that there are no square brackets around the ellipsis. **The arguments of the callback are completely unconstrained** in this case (and keyword arguments are acceptable).

Since it is *"unconstrained"* the following is unlikely to cause the static type checker to issue any warnings because of arguments:

```py
Callable[..., tr]
```

Worth noting, the relation between `Callable`, `Any` and `...` (Ellipsis).

> [*"The `Any` type"*, PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-any-type)
>
> As well, a bare Callable in an annotation is equivalent to Callable[..., Any]

---

---

Finally, if you run your code through [MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8) the expected warning is in fact issued:

> main.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "call_function" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "Callable[[], int]"
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

I checked your example in *PyCharm 2020.2 Pro* and the IDE does not issue the above warning. Notice that [PyCharm uses its own implementation of PEP 484](https://github.com/python/mypy#ide-linter-integrations-and-pre-commit), and their static type checker [has been know to have bugs](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20PyCharm%20callable).

I think you found a bug...

- Final Note: Running `type(None)` gives `NoneType`. In [Python 3 `NoneType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706626) isn't exposed for import although [in Python 2 it was importable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType).
- EDIT: For some reason Python 3.10 is [reintroducing `types.NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html#types.NoneType).