# None vs NoneType for type annotation

Tags: python, nonetype, python-typing, typing

If a function can return `None`, shouldn't the type annotation use `NoneType`?

For example, shouldn't we use this:

```py
from types import NoneType

def my_function(num: int) -> int | NoneType:

    if num > 0:
        return num

    return None
```

instead of:

```py
def my_function(num: int) -> int | None:

    if num > 0:
        return num

    return None
```

?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, both PEP and MyPy say `None`. Are you saying they're wrong?

Comment: Related [Where is the `NoneType` located in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308923)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. [`types.NoneType` was removed in Python 3](https://bugs.python.org/issue19438). Attempting to import `NoneType` from `types` will produce an `ImportError` in Python 3, before Python 3.10. (For Python 3.10, `types.NoneType` was reintroduced; however, for the purposes of type hinting, `types.NoneType` and `None` are equivalent, and you should prefer the latter for conciseness.)

In [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator), `int | None` is the way to describe a return type that could possibly be `None`. However, for Python versions earlier than 3.10, this syntax is unsupported, so you should use `Optional[int]` instead.

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/types.py#L304

Comment: Also I saw this, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#using-none does it mean both are fine? And if both are fine which one should I prefer?

Comment: [This PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) uses `None` over `NoneType`, and the [`mypy` documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#optional-types-and-the-none-type) suggests using `None` (although this is in a section that may not have been updated with respect to Python 3.10). Regardless, I would suggest using `None` as it's more concise.

Comment: At the very least, trying to import `NoneType` produces an import error on Python 3.8.

Comment: Ok, thank you for confirming. I will use `None` in the future.

Comment: I've actually found something interesting in the documentation. Here https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.NoneType, it says `NoneType` is new in Python 3.10. I think they may have added it back? When I import NoneType, it does not cause an error, but I am using Python 3.10. It is also mentioned in the release notes: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#types.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's new to Python 3.10. [This discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue41810) describes the decision to add it into Python 3.10 for consistency reasons (to support ellipsis in static typechecking).

Comment: Functionally, there is no difference -- [`None` is replaced by `type(None)` for type hinting purposes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases). So, I'd still suggest using `None` over `NoneType`.