# How can lists be distinguished depending on the types of their items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, xmltodict

I have converted some XML files with `xmltodict` to native Python types (so it "feel[s] like [I am] working with JSON"). The converted objects have a lot of `"P"` keys with values that might be one of:

- a list of strings
- a list of `None` and a string.
- a list of dicts
- a list of lists of dicts

If the list contain only strings or if the list contain only strings and `None`, then it should be converted to a string using join. If the list contain `dict`s or `list`s then it should be skipped without processing.

How can the code tell these cases apart, so as to determine which action should be performed?

Example data for the first two cases, which should be joined:

```
["Bla Bla"]
[null,"Bla bla"]
```

Example data for the last two cases, which should be skipped:

```
[{"CPV_CODE":{"CODE":79540000}}]
[
  [{"CPV_CODE":{"CODE":79530000}}, {"CPV_CODE":{"CODE":79540000}}],
  [{"CPV_CODE":{"CODE":79550000}}]
]
```

This is done in a function that processes the data:

```py
def recursive_iter(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for item in obj.values():
            if "P" in obj and isinstance(obj["P"], list) and not isinstance(obj["P"], dict):
                #need to add a check for not dict and list in list
                obj["P"] = " ".join([str(e) for e in obj["P"]])
            else:
                yield from recursive_iter(item)
    elif any(isinstance(obj, t) for t in (list, tuple)):
        for item in obj:
            yield from recursive_iter(item)
    else:
        yield obj
```

Comment: By "only find the list with strings", do you mean "convert each list of strings to a string (by joining)" ? In other words, is your question how do you convert only the lists of strings and ignore lists containing other types?

Comment: Yes, if the list contain only strings or if the list contain only stings and null. Then I will have it converted with join. If the list contain dict or list(s) then it will pass.

Comment: By "pass", do you mean `yield`, or do you mean "skip without processing"? Please edit clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: `null` isn't a literal in Python. Do you mean `None`?

Comment: Yes, so I try this one but it failed. if all([isinstance(z, str) for z in obj["P"]]) or ([isinstance(z, None) for z in obj["P"]]):

Comment: if all([isinstance(z, str) for z in obj["P"]]) or ([isinstance(z, type(None)) for z in obj["P"]]): So now I get "SHORT_DESCR": {"P": "None Bla Bla".. Thank you @Cloudy

Comment: Again, please edit clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Those edits clarified much, thanks. I made a few other improvements (mostly to make it easier for others with the same problem to find & understand this question). There's one ambiguous point still remaining that I see: if `None` is in the list, will the list always have 2 items, `None` followed by a string, or might there be lists that are a mix of `None` and strings (e.g. `['a', 'b', None, 'd']`)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to find the list with strings

```
if ("P" in obj) and isinstance(obj["P"], list):
    if all([isinstance(z, str) for z in obj["P"]]):
        ...  # keep list with strings
```

is it what you want?

Comment: With yours code it will not work when "P": ["Bla 1 Bla]

Comment: `"Bla 1 Bla` this string miss a quote mark? I think json file shouldn't miss quote mark, if so, it cannot be parsed by most programs.

Comment: yes, you are right. "SHORT_DESCR": {"P": [null,"Bla bla"]} this one failed. its the null in front

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the two conditions:

1. the list contains only strings or the list contains only strings and null / none
2. the list contains dict or list(s)

The first subcondition of the first condition is covered by the second subcondition, so #1 can be simplified to:

1. the list contains only strings or `None`

Now let's rephrase them in something resembling a [first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic):

1. All the list items are `None` or strings.
2. Some list item is a `dict` or a `list`.

The way that condition #2 is written, it could use an "All" quantifier, but in the context of the operation (whether or not to join the list items), a "some" is appropriate, and more closely aligns with the negation of condition 1 ("Some list item is not `None` or a string"). Also, it allows for an illustration of another implementation (shown below).

These two conditions are mutually exclusive, though not necessarily exhaustive. To simplify matters, let's assume that, in practice, these are the only two possibilities. Leaving aside the quantifiers ("All", "Some"), these are easily translatable into [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

1. `(None == item or isinstance(item, str) for item in items)`
2. `(isinstance(item, (dict, list)) for item in items)`

Note that [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) accepts a tuple of types (which basically functions as a union type) for the second argument, allowing multiple types to be checked in one call. You could make use of this to combine the two tests into one by using [`NoneType`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21706609/90527) (`isinstance(item, (str, types.NoneType))` or `isinstance(item, (str, type(None)))`), but this doesn't gain you much of anything.

The "All" and "Some" quantifiers are expressed as the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) functions, which take iterables (such as what is produced by generator expressions):

1. `all(item is None or isinstance(item, str) for item in items)`
2. `any(isinstance(item, (dict, list)) for item in items)`

Abstracting these expressions into functions gives two options for the implementation. From `recursive_iter`, it looks like the value for a "P" might not always be a list. To guard against this, a `isinstance(items, list)` condition is included:

```
# 1
def shouldJoin(items):
    return isinstance(items, list) and all([item is None or isinstance(item, str) for item in items])

# 2
def shouldJoin(items):
    return isinstance(items, list) and not any([isinstance(item, (dict, list)) for item in items])
```

If you want a more general version of condition #2, you can use [container abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html):

```
import collections.abc as abc

def shouldJoin(items):
    return isinstance(items, list) and not any(isinstance(item, (abc.Mapping, abc.MutableSequence)) for item in items)
```

Both `str` and `list` share many abstract base classes; `MutableSequence` is the one that is unique to `list`, so that is what's used in the sample. To see exactly which ABCs each concrete type descends from, you can play around with the following:

```
import collections.abc as abc
ABCMeta = type(abc.Sequence)
abcs = {name: val for (name, val) in abc.__dict__.items() if isinstance(val, ABCMeta)}

def abcsOf(t):
    return {name for (name, kls) in abcs.items() if issubclass(t, kls)}

# examine ABCs
abcsOf(str)
abcsOf(list)
# which ABCs does list descend from, that str doesn't?
abcsOf(list) - abcsOf(str)
# result: {'MutableSequence'}
abcsOf(tuple) - abcsOf(str)
# result: set() (the empty set)
```

Note that it's not possible to distinguish `str`s from `tuple`s using just ABCs.

### Other Notes

The expression `any(isinstance(obj, t) for t in (list, tuple))` can be simplified to `isinstance(obj, (list, tuple))`.

#### Dict Loop Bug

All the references to `"P" in obj` and `obj["P"]` in the first `for` loop of `recursive_iter` are [loop-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). This means, in general and at the very least, there's an opportunity for [loop optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion). However, in this case since the branch tests an item other than the current item, it indicates a bug. How it should be fixed depends on whether or not the joined string should be yielded. If so, the test & join can be moved outside the loop, and the loop will then yield the modified value of "P":

```
    # ...
        if "P" in obj and shouldJoin(obj["P"]):
            obj["P"] = " ".join([str(item) for item in obj["P"]])
        for value in obj.values():
            yield from recursive_iter(value)
    #...
```

If not, there are a couple options (note you can use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to get the keys & their values simultaneously):

1. Move the test & join outside the loop (as for if the joined "P" should be yielded), but skip the modified value for "P" within the loop:

   ```
   # ...
   if "P" in obj and shouldJoin(obj["P"]):
       obj["P"] = " ".join([str(item) for item in obj["P"]])
   for (key, value) in obj.items():
       if not ("P" == key and isinstance(value, str)):
           yield from recursive_iter(item)
   ```
2. Move the test & join outside the loop (as for if the joined "P" should be yielded), but exclude "P" from the loop:

   ```
   # ...
   values = (value for value in obj.values())
   if "P" in obj and shouldJoin(obj["P"]):
       obj["P"] = " ".join([str(item) for item in obj["P"]])
       values = (value for (key, value) in obj.items() if "P" != key)
   for value in values:
       yield from recursive_iter(value)
   ```
3. Keep the test & join in the loop, but test the current key. In general, you need to be careful about modifying objects while looping over them as that may invalidate or interfere with iterators. In this particular case, `dict.items` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), so modifying values shouldn't cause problems (though adding or removing values will cause a runtime error).

   ```
   # ...
   for (key, value) in obj.items():
       if "P" == key and shouldJoin(value):
           obj["P"] = " ".join([str(item) for item in value])
       else:
           yield from recursive_iter(item)
   ```