# python "nonetype" object error, but it seems not none value

Tags: python, list, nonetype

```
def triangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    if n == 1:
        return [[1]]
    else:
        before = triangle(n - 1)
        calculate = [0] + before[-1] + [0]
        now = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(calculate) - 1:
            now.append(calculate[i] + calculate[i + 1])
            i = i + 1
        print now
        return before.append(now)


#Expected output:

print triangle(0)
#>>> []

print triangle(1)
#>>> [[1]]

print triangle(2)
#>> [[1], [1, 1]]

print triangle(3)
#>>> [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]

print triangle(6)
#>>> [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]]
```

in this code, when the input value is 2, returned None. if the input velue is more then 2, the code referenced triangle(2), and Nonetype object error occurred

[with a little googleing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object), I know the this error is because of None value.

```
>>> bar = "something"
>>> foo = None
>>> print foo + bar
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

but i think the code not concatenate None velue.

```
return before.append(now)
```

this code concatenate before and now.
so i wrote debug code like this.

```
        print "before is"
        print before
        print "now is"
        print now
        return before.append(now)
```

the result is

```
triangle(2)

before is
[[1]]
now is
[1, 1]
None
```

before and now, both are not None!

I already re-write the code several times, but all code has error. Pleace help me! i using python 2.

it is first time to using stackoverflow, so pleace notice me if i contrary to regulations

Comment: aaah the infamous `return before.append(now)`. returns none all the time

Comment: `return before + [now]`

Comment: Thank you! I solve like this result = before + [now]    return result
but why? why i have to like this?

Comment: I found duplicate answer! I found reason!