# Is there anything in Python that is a `NoneType` besides `None`?

Tags: python, types, nonetype

I was just wondering if in Python there's any other object/instance whose type is `NoneType` type besides the very well known `None`:

```
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

So... This is very clear, but I was wondering whether there's *anything* else that is also of `NoneType`

```
>>> type(???)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Needless to say, this is just for curiosity sake and learning purposes **:-)**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095702/1084416) to this question: [What is a `NoneType` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object)

Comment: Welp, if an answer answers a question in an indirect dupe, it's still a dupe.

Comment: You're right... it's a duplicate (I saw that question, and I didn't get as far as to reach the 3rd entry) I'll accept the first answer and remove it

Comment: @BorrajaX Relax. There's nothing wrong with dupes. They serve as checkpoints to guide people who enter different search terms but are looking for the same thing.

Comment: See also the source code: [`object.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L1548)

Comment: Ok... That makes sense @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ... I'll keep it for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs, [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) is:

> The sole value of the type `NoneType`.

Comment: dang, you people that make Stack Overflow are great **:-D**

Comment: People that read the documentation to find answers?

Comment: I did, `a p`, but it's no so clear in the Python 2 docs, which is what I use (https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType)

Comment: It's in python 2 docs too: https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html

Comment: Right you are, @roganjosh... I don't know how could I miss that! **:-S**

Answer (score 3):

`None` is the only `NoneType` , however in your case of

```
>>> type(???)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

You could do something like

```
>>> a=None
>>> type(a)
type 'NoneType'
```

Meaning, any variable that holds `None` will obviously also return `NoneType` as its type since they are `None`.

Comment: `a` is not a value; it's just another name that refers to the singleton value of type `NoneType`.

Comment: That's why I included the example with `a` , since the asker's question wonders `whether there's anything else`, so I took that to include names that refers to the very same `NoneType`.