# python2::TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, node.js

I'm starting experimenting Python and I can't understand what's wrong with my code... I'm getting:
[image: tips]
I get an error for line 86 and line 34 which says TypeErroe:unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Please help me solve this problem !

> python code.py:

```
def build(string, path, name, logo=""):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
         version = 2,
         error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
         box_size = 10,
         border = 1
    )
    qr.add_data(string)
    qr.make( fit = True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    icon = Image.open(logo+'.png')
    img_w, img_h = img.size
    factor = 4
    size_w = int(img_w / factor)
    size_h = int(img_h / factor)
    icon_w, icon_h = icon.size
    if icon_w > size_w: icon_w = size_w
    if icon_h > size_h: icon_h = size_h
    icon = icon.resize((icon_w, icon_h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    w = int((img_w - icon_w) / 2)
    h = int((img_h - icon_h) / 2)
    icon = icon.convert("RGBA")
    newimg = Image.new("RGBA", (icon_w + 8, icon_h + 8), (255, 255, 255))
    img.paste(newimg, (w-4, h-4), newimg)
    img.paste(icon, (w, h), icon)
    img.save(path + name + '.png', quality = 100)
    file = path + name + '.png'
    return file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument('Words')
    argparser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', default = os.getcwd())
    argparser.add_argument('-n', '--name')
    argparser.add_argument('-l', '--logo')
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    try:
        file = build(
            args.Words,
            args.directory,
            args.name,
            args.logo
        )
        print (str(file))
    except:
        raise
```

> node code.js:

```
const child = require('child_process');
child.exec('python code.py http://xx.com/down?name=client&type=1&shopId=1001 -n service -l ./img/service -d ./', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: Looks like from error, logo is None object. Print the value of  args.logo before passing to function build. To check is it pointing to None. You can also check this link for more info on None https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object

Comment: I think it's url  '&'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your logo variable is NULL (no value in it None Type).First check whether it is still None Type or not.

```
if(logo !=None ): # or if logo is not None:
 image = logo + '.png'
else:
  #put what you want to do
icon = Image.open(image)
```