# Replacing value in whole dataframe if part of the string match

Tags: python, pandas, replace, python-re

I am trying to replace the value in my whole dataframe if part of the string match. I tried to use `df.replace` `df.str.contains` etc but none of them are working.  Here are similar questions but they are not answering my question [sample][1]:

I have datframe like this:
df

```
Brand                        2Brand                         3Brand
Audi                          BMW                           None of the above
None from list                BMW                           Audi
None                          None below or above           BMW
NaN                           Audi                          NaN
```

I just want to replace everywhere None appear.

The desired otput would be like this:

```
Brand                        2Brand                         3Brand
Audi                          BMW                           None
None                          BMW                           Audi
None                          None                          BMW
NaN                           Audi                          NaN
```

Comment: Still not working with real data?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) per columns in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), for avoid convert possible `None` and `NaN` values is used `na=False` parameter:

```
df = df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('None', na=False)), 'None')
print (df)
  Brand 2Brand 3Brand
0  Audi    BMW   None
1  None    BMW   Audi
2  None   None    BMW
```

EDIT: If possible some numeric columns use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for get only strings columns (obviously objects ate strings) and then add to mask numeric column filled by `False` by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
            Brand               2Brand             3Brand  col
0            Audi                  BMW  None of the above    4
1  None from list                  BMW               Audi    7
2            None  None below or above                BMW    9
3             NaN                 Audi                NaN    5

mask = (df.select_dtypes(object)
          .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('None', na=False))
          .reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False, axis=1))
df = df.mask(mask, None)
print (df)
  Brand 2Brand 3Brand  col
0  Audi    BMW   None    4
1  None    BMW   Audi    7
2  None   None    BMW    9
3   NaN   Audi    NaN    5
```

Comment: Thanks but i have alot of columns and dont want to change datatype for all and as i need to apply to whole df. There are some columns which have no str data type... so i am getting this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: I dont want to change NaN values. They should remain NaN. I want to change only where there is Keyword 'None'. Its working but it changed all the NaN values to 'None" too.

Comment: @s_khan92 - Do you need replace to `None` like [Nonetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object) or like `None` like string `'None'` ?

Comment: Only a string "None"

Comment: @s_khan92 - Ok, so need `('None', na=True)` change to `('None', na=False)`  and `df.mask(mask, None)` to `df.mask(mask, 'None')`

Comment: It changed all the values with "Obj" datatype to None whether there is string "None" or not. I just want to change the values "None" when the part of the string contains "None" in the values.

Comment: I made small edit in my question. I add another extra row where there is NaN value that i dont want to change. I just want to change the values where there is a string "None" like` "None of the above"` -> `'None' or 'None of the below"` -> `'None'`. There are `NaN` values but no `NoneType`, i dont want to change NaN values.

Comment: I don't know why its not working on my dataframe.. There are some values which contains string like 'YouTube' and 'Facebook' and that are also converted to None

Comment: @s_khan92 - it seems data related problem, there are not strings like `YouTube some long string None` ?

Comment: I added the original dataframe screeshot.

Comment: @s_khan92 - Unfortuantely I am cannot check type or data from picture, I need real data for find problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
In [1732]: df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: 'None' in x), None)
Out[1732]: 
  Brand 2Brand 3Brand
0  Audi    BMW   None
1  None    BMW   Audi
2  None   None    BMW
```