# Discord Bot - "Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip.'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm a new coder, and I've been following a[tutorial](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#how-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-python) on how to create a discord bot with the code below having been virtually copied the code straight out from the tutorial, and I've create a .env file to store my AuthToken.  Every time I run the code, I get error below aforementioned code. Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
import os 

import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/XXXXXXXXXXXX/scratch/discordbot/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: I know you cannot share the token but are you sure you defined the token right in the `.env` file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did.  Basically looks like DISCORD_TOKEN = XXXXXXXXXXX... to give you an idea of what I did. I'm just confused because it seems like there might be an issue accessing the `.env`  file even though I've got all the updated modules installed. I don't know much, but I can't think of anything else that might be going wrong.

Comment: Try it without the spaces. In the tutorial there are no spaces between `DISCORD_TOKEN` and its value.

Answer (score 8):

I was following the same tutorial and ran into the same error. Issue for me was that I had created the ".env" file incorrectly. In the tutorial it says "Create a file named .env in the same directory as bot.py:" - this was my issue. If you create a new text document, paste in the code, then save it with the name ".env", what you'll *actaully* be creating is a text file called ".env.txt".

To get around this, go to the directory where you have the python script saved (for me this is C:\Thonny\DiscordBots), then right-click in that folder and select "New > Text Document". Don't change the filename yet, just leave it as "New Text Document". Open this file (should open in Notepad), then paste in the code from the tutorial (also, remember to substitute your bot's actual token in for the placeholder variable called {your-bot-token}). Now, go to "File > Save As" and in the *File Name* field, type ".env" just like the tutorial says to; **BEFORE you hit save, also click the *Save as type* dropdown** (should be right below *File Name*) and instead of leaving it as the default type (*.txt), change this to "All Files".

If you've done this correctly, you should see your ".env" file in file explorer, and the "Type" column will now show "ENV File" instead of "text document". Try to run the code again.

This is what helped me. My understanding is that "load_dotenv()" is looking for a file of the ENV *type*, not just *any* document called ".env" (of any type). As long as this file is placed in the same directory as the script you're running, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

This error arises due to the failure of fetching TOKEN value in. env file which can be resolved by-

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('---.env')
```

It worked for me !!!

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to `TOKEN` being set to `None`, which is what `os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')` returns if the variable doesn't exist or it exists and is set to `None`.

Make sure your .env file is in the same directory, for example:

```
.
├── .env
└── bot.py
```

The token is an environment variable, not a python variable. Assignment of environment variables follow the syntax of the shell you are using. This means no spaces around the `=` sign.

Note the order of operations when using `dotenv` to export variables to your shell (see readme [here](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv)):

> Python-dotenv can interpolate variables using POSIX variable
> expansion.
>
> The value of a variable is the first of the values defined in the
> following list:
>
> - Value of that variable in the environment.
> - Value of that variable in the .env file.
> - Default value, if provided.
> - Empty string.
>
> Ensure that
> variables are surrounded with {} like ${HOME} as bare variables such
> as $HOME are not expanded.

And the example given is:

```
CONFIG_PATH=${HOME}/.config/foo
DOMAIN=example.org
EMAIL=admin@${DOMAIN}
DEBUG=${DEBUG:-false
```

For this reason, you may need to clear your relevant shell variables before proceeding, as the first thing `dotenv` will try is to use the already defined variable, which was probably set to an empty string on your initial setup (e.g. `unset DISCORD_TOKEN`, or restarting your shell with something like `source ~/.bashrc` or similar).

For debugging purposes, I would recommend `print(os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN'))` to see exactly what this variable is set to. You might also try seeing the output of `load_dotenv(verbose=True)` during the environment setup.

Comment: You're totally right about the name - fixed that. And I did make adjustments to the `.env` file to have no spaces, but it still came up with the same error. I tried a couple of different ways of writing it, to no success

Comment: What about making it a string? (i.e. `DISCORD_TOKEN="my-token-here"`)

Comment: Tried that just now, unfortunately same result  (thank you for the suggestions btw, i really do appreciate the help!)

Comment: Can  you see what the output of `load_dotenv(verbose=True)` is?

Comment: Just tried it now, and same result - it didn't change the output of the error type

Comment: You probably have to wrap it in a print statement to get output (e.g. `print(load_dotenv(verbose=True))` or something like `load_output = load_dotenv(verbose=True)` then `print(load_output)`.

Comment: Just tried that and now I'm still getting that same error, but at the top of the error it now says "File doesn't exist." What does the command verbose=True do within the code? Apologies if that's a super simple question, I'm still very new to everything!

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the `load_env()` function call goes looking for your .env file but can't find it. where is your .env file relative to your bot.py file? The `dotenv` library is on git hub here: https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/tree/d83c1b65ceab5cf1223c41649a25a142755fe703

Comment: I created it under the same directory as my bot.py file by just adding it via the new file action in Visual Studio Code. I'll check out that library to see if I can figure anything from there

Comment: Change your import statement to `from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv` then call `print(find_dotenv('.env', True, False))` and `print(find_dotenv('.env', True, True))`  to see if dotenv is finding your environment file, where your environment file is called '.env', the 2nd `True` is to raise an error if not found, and the 3rd bool is whether or not to start looking in the current directory. This is all covered in the python-dotenv/src/dotenv/main.py file at the git hub repo I linked to earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In your .env file, is it like "BOT_TOKEN={WHAT_EVER_TOKEN}" or something else?
If it is that, then it'll be wrong
The correct way is "BOT_TOKEN=WHAT_EVER_TOKEN", just without the "{}"

Comment: I know this problem because I have met this problem before, and it's the EXACT same... if that doesn't work, then it's probably something with the IDE or something.

Comment: there aren't supposed to be anything, just the token itself and the 'variable'.

Answer (score 1):

Been looking around a few forums then came across this - life savers thank you!

Sorted now with;

```
load_dotenv('Token.env')
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

Token.env;
```

DISCORD_TOKEN=*Token here*

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem where `load_dotenv()` wouldn't find the .env file located in the same exact folder as my .py file which resulted in the error **Attribute Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'**.

I tried a bunch of different fixes, from `load_dotenv(find_dotenv())` to `os.envrion['TOKEN']` instead of `os.getenv("TOKEN")` as well as all the other fixes other people gave us in this stack overflow thread. You may have tried those already with no luck like I had.

To get around this, I used:

```
load_dotenv(dotenv_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\DiscordBot\discordbot.env")
```

This specifies the exact file that load_dotenv() will load (I think). Take note of `os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())`. This returns the *current working directory* (getcwd()) of where your project file is located. In my case, it would return this string:
`F:\dev\Python\YaykobDiscordBot`.

My actual .py file was located deeper, in another folder: `"F:\dev\Python\YaykobDiscordBot\DiscordBot\YaykobBot.py"`, and in the same file right next to it was
`"F:\dev\Python\YaykobDiscordBot\DiscordBot\discordbot.env"` which is where I store my token.

You may notice that really, you just need to give `load_dotenv()` the file path of wherever the .env file is located. In my case, I can write:
`load_dotenv(dotenv_path = "F:\dev\Python\YaykobDiscordBot\DiscordBot\discordbot.env")` and it would work perfectly. I use `os.path.abspath` because it works whenever I want to clone my repository from Github.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the spaces from the .env file. So if you file looks like this

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = 1234ABC
```

It wont accept it. It needs to look like this

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=1234ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I know how to solve it. So basically for some reason vscode won't accept os.getenv(TOKEN). So what I did was to put the token directly into the client.run("Your TOKEN here") function.

Comment: Although this is a solution, it is strongly recommended to avoid using tokens, passwords or other sensitive data directly in the productive code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the read token is a ['NoneType' object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095731/13739298).

So if you use `client.run(str(TOKEN))` instead of `client.run(TOKEN)` the method should be able to handle the token correctly and your bot should work.