# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' when trying to make a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot using python and when I run basic code it returns "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'"
I'm following [this](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/) tutorial.
I have 2 files - bot.py and bot.env(to store the token)
Here are the 2 files:
bot.py:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} has connected to Discord!")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

and bot.env:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN={token}
```

It should display "{bot name} has connected to Discord!"
I googled the error but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot - "Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682769/discord-bot-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-strip)

Comment: If you would like to store the token in your code just write TOKEN = "your token" (at the beginning of the script). Then you can delete:

 1. import os
 2. from dotenv import load_dotenv
 3. load_dotenv()
 4. TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
or try looking for the solution in the question @LeoGaunt linked

Comment: Thank you for the help! I don't know how I missed that same question but storing the token in the code helped.

Comment: If you solved your answer, it'll be good if you share the solution to other people.

Comment: @Nurqm I already did that...? Storing the token in the variable TOKEN rather than in a separate .env file solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a new line and load the env as what  @RiveN has mentioned

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many problems occur while storing token in enviroment variables, So I'd recommend storing it inside a file and reading it or making a python file with function that returns token and then importing it.
When you host your bot on an external hosting server, you can't access these variables. So, You will at some point, need to change this method of getting token.