# Python Traceback (most recent call last) Issue while coding discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Recently did some random coding and I keep getting this error message. What do I do?

The Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSSMu.png

The Code:

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('sleep start'): 
        await message.channel.send('Welcome to Sleepy Quest! A world of dumb adventures now await you!')

client.run(os.getenv('Discord Bot Token (Deleted for private stuff)'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot - "Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682769/discord-bot-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-strip)

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](/tour) Please see [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Please do not post code/errors as images; post them as text. Also, [format your code](/editing-help). And please [edit] your question to include the full code. I don't see any `.strip` in the code you've posted; we can't help.

Comment: If it's an error in the module, check if you've written your code correctly and the arguments passed. Also, if you're using Repl.it, check if you have stored it correctly as you should in Repl.it. You probably have to store it in some other file.

Answer (score 0):

You leaked the token anyway in that screenshot. Reset it now.

It wasn't addressed in the dupe, but the issue is that your "key" is actually the token itself, not a variable. When it isn't found, then it will return `None`, which `discord.py` tries to interpret as a string, causing that error.

Since you're pasting the token anyway, just pass that normally:

```py
client.run('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```