# Discord.py voiceClient.play() is not recognised

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a music bot is discord.py and I've been able to make the bot join a channel and download YouTube audio but when it tries to play the audio, [this error occurs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7v1I.png) Please help me in what to do as I have already tried to search through google and stack overflow and I can't find anything. The error happens when I try to run the play command.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import os


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")


@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the currently playing music to end or use the 'stop' command.")

    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="testing")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if not voice.is_connected():
            await channel.connect()
    else:
        await channel.connect()

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': "bestaudio",
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': "FFmpegExtractAudio",
            'preferredcodec': "mp3",
            'preferredquality': "192"
        }]
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if voice.is_connected():
            await voice.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("There is no channel to leave.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("There is no channel to leave.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if voice.is_playing():
            voice.pause()
        else:
            await ctx.send("No audio is playing.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am currently not in a channel.")


@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if voice.is_paused():
            voice.resume()
        else:
            await ctx.send("Audio is already playing.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am currently not in a channel.")


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if voice.is_playing:
            voice.stop()
        else:
            await ctx.send("No audio is playing.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am currently not in a channel.")

client.run(Token)
```

Comment: `NoneType` = Something does not exist/is not returning something. ([Contribution about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when the bot isn't connected to a voice channel before executing the command, voice is `None`. You can fix this by updating both `await channel.connect()` to `voice = await channel.connect()`:

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the currently playing music to end or use the 'stop' command.")

    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="testing")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if not voice.is_connected():
            voice = await channel.connect()
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect() 

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': "bestaudio",
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': "FFmpegExtractAudio",
            'preferredcodec': "mp3",
            'preferredquality': "192"
        }]
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
```