# python) how to solve this nontype problem?

Tags: python

```
def manage_account(balance, choice, money):
    if choice == '+':
        balance = balance + money
        return balance
    elif choice =='-':
        if balance > money:
            balance= balance - money
            return balance
        elif balance < money:
            print('There is not enough money in your account')
    else:
        print('ERROR')

balance = 10000    
balance = manage_account(balance, '-', 20000)
balance = manage_account(balance, '-', 5000)
balance = manage_account(balance, '=', 20000)
balance = manage_account(balance, '+', 1000)
```

why nontype problem happened? Ans how can i escape this awful situation?

Comment: Your function lacks a `return` statement. Hence it returns None.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67439738/10952503) help you ? (other another answer)

Comment: A hint for you next question: Please always include the error message you get. In this case it was quite easy to spot your problem, but in future this helps others help you.

Comment: And another hint: Try to reduce your code to a minimum example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example And you could use a debugging technique, such as using `breakpoint()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function lacks a `return` statement, for the case that the account amount gets negative. Then it returns `None`.

That is why `balance = manage_account(balance, '-', 20000)` is `None`, and when you call the function the second time, an error is raised at `balance - money`. An analogue problem occurs when passing `'='` as parameter `choice` to the function a couple of lines below.

Depending on what is the desired behavior of your function, you should consider using a `raise ValueError` instead of printing Error.