# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' in mitmproxy

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am getting the following error. Can anyone help me in this matter?
Addon error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mitmInterceptor.py", line 149, in response
connect_time = (flow.server_conn.timestamp_tcp_setup -
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
if (flow.server_conn and flow.server_conn not in SERVERS_SEEN):
    connect_time = (flow.server_conn.timestamp_tcp_setup -
                    flow.server_conn.timestamp_start)

    if (flow.server_conn.timestamp_tls_setup is not None):
        ssl_time = (flow.server_conn.timestamp_tls_setup -
                    flow.server_conn.timestamp_tcp_setup)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error *means*, at the most immediate level? If not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095731/4177009) might be interesting.

Comment: `mitmInterceptor.py` is not a file of the current MitmProxy version. So you are using an outdated version of Mitmproxy or a third party script we don't know. Therefore we can't help you until you exactly describe what version of Mitmproxy you use and what this `mitmInterceptor.py` script is.

Comment: I am using mitmporxy version 7.0.4 and mitmInterceptor.py is the python file where above code consists.

Comment: I am getting error on line  connect_time = (flow.server_conn.timestamp_tcp_setup -
                    flow.server_conn.timestamp_start)

Comment: Without knowing the context of your code we can only say that your code seem to be incompatible with Mitmproxy 7.0.4. Add a break-point ant the line where the error occurs and run it. If the break point hits inspect `flow.server_conn` to see the properties that exist.