# What exactly a None type is?

Tags: python, nonetype, pulp

Here is the function that I receive the warning from (when v.varValue >= 1, it says "'>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int')

```
def print_prob(prob, timelimit):
    for v in prob.variables():
        if (v.varValue >= 1):
            print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

    print(value(prob.objective))

    if timelimit >= 0:
        print("Tempo de execução restante:", timelimit)
        print("Tempo de execução total:", max_time - timelimit)
    else:
        print("O ótimo não foi encontrado com o tempo dado.")
    #print(prob)

return
```

What I'm doing in a global way is going through a list of files, each file having different sizes and different values. I open the file, get what I need from it (size and matrix of costs), assign it to some variables and send them to a function. This function creates other variables, including the 'v', using the variables I've got from the file (basically making a dictionary/list of lists), then I try solving a function using this v and a bunch of other restrictions. After solving it, I try to print it along with the variables which got "chosen" (if v[i][j] >= 1, then it's chosen and should be printed).

```
def testing_all_3(i):
    #these are the file names
    file = ['wi29', 'dj38', 'qa194', 'uy734', 'zi929', 'lu980', 'rw1621', 'mu1979', 'nu3496', 'ca4663']
    print("===============")
    print("Testando o arquivo", file[i] + ".tsp")
    #I open the current file using a special function 
    #(the file type is TSP, which has its own library to work with)
    bench = _tspfile(file[i] + ".tsp")
    n = bench.dimension
#n = testing_all_3(i)
    #I use the data that I got from the file, making a list of nodes 
    #(which I represent with numbers)
    cidades, destinos = _append(n)
    #the weight of each node that I transform into a dictionary for Pulp
    costs = _tsp(n, bench)
    costs = makeDict([cidades, destinos], costs, 0)
    #prob = creating(cidades, destinos)

    #Then I call two function that are very similar for solving the problem
    print("Resolvendo com MTZ")
    solvingMTZ(cidades, destinos, n, costs, file[i])
    print("===============")
    print("Testando o arquivo", file[i] + ".tsp")
    print("Resolvendo com DL")
    solvingDL(cidades, destinos, n, costs, file[i])

for i in range(5,10):
    #I would make this range from 0 to 9
    #but I only get the warning at the 4th and beyond file
    testing_all_3(i)
```

This is the function where the other functions are called and variables are created

```
def solvingMTZ(cidades, destinos, n, costs, file):
    prob = LpProblem("Teste", LpMinimize)
    road = [(cid_i, cid_j) for cid_i in cidades for cid_j in destinos]
    var = LpVariable.dicts("Road", (cidades, destinos), 0, 1, LpInteger)

    prob += lpSum([var[cid_i][cid_j] * costs[cid_i][cid_j] for (cid_i, cid_j) in road]) #função obj

    for i in cidades:
        prob += lpSum([var[i][cid_j] for cid_j in destinos if i != cid_j]) == 1 #única entrada

    for j in destinos:
        prob += lpSum([var[cid_i][j] for cid_i in cidades if j != cid_i]) == 1 #única saída

    prob = mtz(n, prob, cidades, var)
    timelimit = max_time
    start = time.time()
    prob.solve(GUROBI_CMD(timeLimit=timelimit, msg=1, gapRel=0))
    end = time.time()
    timelimit = timelimit - end + start
    print(timelimit)


#imprimo os valores das variáveis e o resultado final da função
    print_prob(prob, timelimit)
    make_node_fileMTZ(prob, file, timelimit)
return

#the function I called to help solving the problem
#the DL one (solvingDL) is nearly identical, so I didn't add it here
def mtz(n, prob, cidades, var):
    u = LpVariable.dicts('u', (i for i in cidades), 1, n-1, LpInteger)
    for i in cidades[1:]:
        for j in cidades[1:]:
        #if i != j:
            prob += u[i] - u[j] + (n - 1) * var[i][j] <= n - 2
    return prob
```

I'm currently coding on python and I started to get this problem "'>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'". Basically, there's a dictionary from Pulp, called 'v' for variable, and I try printing out each one of its contents, saying "if this value is >= 1, then print the variable name and its value".

The real thing is, I don't know how this get a None type, because it's not the first time I'm running the code like this, I actually run the same thing with 3 different sizes and all of them work, but at the 4th time and beyond it keeps stating this warning. I looked upon other similar stuff, but I don't think I understand it quite well, like, why this is getting a None "after I increase the number of variables", but it does just fine before that?

Thanks in advance for any advice you may have, kind stranger

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example code snippet that causes the error you are asking about.

Comment: To understand what `NoneType` is, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object. This won't exactly solve your current problem. Note that I googled "python what is nonetype" to find this (basically the words in your title).

Comment: You are alluding to your code but not actually showing it.

Comment: I recommend that you copy/paste the error message into Google. You will find a lot of examples of people that encountered the same problem. Hopefully you will also be able to use their solutions to fix it.

Comment: There is no name in the built-in scope bound to this type. You can get a reference to it, though, with either `type(None)` or via the `types` module with `types.NoneType`.

Answer (score 1):

So the None type exists because *everything* in Python is an object, and all Python functions return an object, so you need an object that represents "no object", which is why there's a None object.

Hard to answer the rest of your question without seeing the code, but the exception will lead you to the exact line of code where it's happening.

Comment: I'm not sure you actually *need* a dedicated type. The vast majority of things that use `None` would work the same with an ordinary name `None = object()`.

Comment: @chepner you don't need it much like you don't really *need* a distinction between signed and unsigned integers, but often it is useful to express salient information through the type system. A distinct type turns out to be useful in subtle emergent permeating ways - for example, it let's things like dynamic dispatch (c.f. `singledispatch` in the standard library) properly dispatch `None` as its own unique case, it means that `isinstance(foo, type(bar))` is actually useful when `bar` happens to be `None`, and composes with constructing instances from `type(foo)` or `class_or_factory_function`.

Comment: @chepnerI suppose it depends on how you interpret "needs". `None` is _bottom_ in the type lattice. If you have nothing for the bottom of the type lattice you need something to serve by convention, as with C NULL being((void*)0).