# Python: filedialog.asksaveasfilename() exits accidentally

Tags: python, tkinter, save, exit, savefiledialog

Recently I'm learning PyQt5 and Tkinter, and I'm implementing a function that saving text as a txt to the address I designated. The codes are here(part of the hole application):

```
import tkinter.messagebox

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import BackgroundClient
import threading
import re
from tkinter import filedialog, dialog
import tkinter as tk

class MyMainForm(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.save_txt_button.clicked.connect(self.generate_txt)
        
    def generate_txt(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
        if file_path is not None:
            file_text = str(self.conversation_bowser.toPlainText())
            with open(file=file_path, mode='a+', encoding='gbk') as file:
                file.write(file_text)
            # tkinter.messagebox.
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("tip", "successful")
        else:
            print("empty file")
            return
```

The codes acted like the picture followed: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czmar.jpg). When I input the address of the file and click 保存(which means "Save"), the file can be saved successfully. However, when I click 取消(which means "Cancel"), no matter the address is empty or not, the application exits with code `-1073740791 (0xC0000409)`.

So what could cause the problem? Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click cancel on the filedialog, your `file_path` variable will be equal to `''` (the empty string) and not `None`.

Thus, you're always running the `if` statement as True, even if there's no filename to target.

EDIT:
The empty string evaluates to `False` (see Python docs on [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) so you could use just `if file_path` to test if you can save the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But what's the difference between None and ''?

Comment: They are different data types. `None` has the type `NoneType` and indicates the absence of a value. Even though `''` or `""` is an empty string with no characters in it, there is still _something_ stored there. Another good explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095731/20948146).