# My function keeps producing the word "none" in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in a beginners computer science class, and for my final I have to create a menu that includes all of my previous coding assignments using only the basic techniques that we have been taught. I have created a code that works, but the problem is my code also produces the word "none" in the output.

```
def options():  
    print ("Pick from the list")
    print ("1. Grade Conversion")
    print ("2. Temperature Conversion")
    print ("3. Currency Conversion")
    print ("4. Sum and Average")
    print ("5. Heads or Tails Guessing Game")
    print ("6. Fibonacci Sequence")
    print ("7. Factorials")
    print ("8. Multiplication Table")
    print ("9. Guess the Number Game")
    print ("10. Calculator")
    print ("11. Exit")

def Student_A_Gets_A():
    print ("Student A gets Grade A")
    print (Score)
def Student_B_Gets_B():
    print ("Student B gets Grade B")  
    print (Score)
def Student_C_Gets_C():
    print ("Student C gets Grade C")
    print (Score)
def Student_D_Gets_D():
    print ("Student D gets Grade D")
    print (Score)
def Student_F_Gets_F():
    print ("Student F gets Grade F")   
    print (Score)

def Celsius():
    Temperature = int(input ("Please enter Temp. in Celsius: "))
    print ("Fahrenheit = ", (Temperature*(9/5))+32)
def Fahrenheit():
    Temperature = int(input ("Please enter Temp. in Fahrenheit: "))
    print ("Celsius = ", (Temperature-32)*(5/9))

def Currency_Conversion():
    print ("Pick from the list")
    print ("1. Dollar to Euro")
    print ("2. Dollar to Peso")
    print ("3. Euro to Dollar")
    print ("4. Peso to Dollar")
    print ("5. Euro to Peso")
    print ("6. Peso to Euro")

def Dollar_to_Euro():
    print ("You have selected 1 to convert Dollar to Euro")
    Amount = int(input("Please enter the amount in dollar(s): "))
    print ("$", Amount, " = ", "€",(Amount)*(0.813654))
def Dollar_to_Peso():
    print ("You have selected 2 to convert Dollar to Peso")
    Amount = int(input("Please enter the amount in dollar(s): "))
    print ("$", Amount, " = ", "Mex$",(Amount)*(18.695653))
def Euro_to_Dollar():
    print ("You have selected 3 to convert Euro to Dollar")
    Amount = int(input("Please enter the amount in euro(s): "))
    print ("€", Amount, " = ", "$",(Amount)/(0.813654))
def Peso_to_Dollar():
    print ("You have selected 4 to convert Peso to Dollar")
    Amount = int(input("Please enter the amount in peso(s): "))
    print ("Mex$", Amount, " = ", "$",(Amount)/(18.695653))
def Euro_to_Peso():
    print ("You have selected 5 to convert Euro to Peso")
    Amount = int(input("Please enter the amount in euro(s): "))
    print ("€", Amount, " = ", "Mex$",(Amount)*(22.98))
def Peso_to_Euro():
    print ("You have selected 6 to convert Peso to Euro")
    Amount = int(input("Please enter the amount in peso(s): "))
    print ("$", Amount, " = ", "€",(Amount)/(22.98))


def options2 ():    
    print ("Select Operation")
    print ("1. Add 2 numbers")
    print ("2. Subtract 2 numbers")
    print ("3. Multiply 2 numbers")
    print ("4. Divide 2 numbers")
    print ("5. Guessing Game")


print (options())
answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 10: "))
while (1):
    if answer < 1 and answer > 11:
        print ("Sorry, that is not an option. Enter a number from 1 through 11")
        print (" ")
        print (options())
        answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 1:
        Score = int(input("Please enter Score: "))
        if Score >= 90 and Score <= 100:
            print (Student_A_Gets_A())
            print (" ")
            print (options ())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Score >= 80 and Score <= 89:
            print (Student_B_Gets_B())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Score >= 70 and Score <= 79:
            print (Student_C_Gets_C())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Score >= 60 and Score <= 69:
            print (Student_D_Gets_D())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Score >= 50 and Score <= 59:
            print (Student_F_Gets_F())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        else:   
            print ("Error: Score must be between 100 and 50 for grades A through F")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 2:
        Celsius_or_Fahrenheit = int(input ("Please enter 1 for Celsius or 2 for Fahrenheit: "))
        if Celsius_or_Fahrenheit == 1:
            print (Celsius())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Celsius_or_Fahrenheit == 2:
            print (Fahrenheit())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        else:
            print ("Error, must choose 1 for Celsius or 2 for Fahrenheit")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 3:
        print (Currency_Conversion())
        Currency_Conversion_answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 6: "))
        if Currency_Conversion_answer == 1:
            print (Dollar_to_Euro())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Currency_Conversion_answer == 2:
            print (Dollar_to_Peso())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Currency_Conversion_answer == 3:
            print (Euro_to_Dollar())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Currency_Conversion_answer == 4:
            print (Peso_to_Dollar())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Currency_Conversion_answer == 5:
            print (Euro_to_Peso())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif Currency_Conversion_answer == 6:
            print (Peso_to_Euro())
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        else:
            print ("Error, number not within bounds")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 4:
        number = int(input("How many numbers would you like to add: "))
        counter = 0
        average = 0
        for j in range(1,number+1):
            if j %10 == 0:
                print (j,",")
            elif j == number:
                print (j)
            else:
                print (j,"," ,end="")
        for i in range(1,number + 1):
            counter += i
            average = counter/number
        print ("sum = ", counter)
        print ("average = ", average)
        print (" ")
        print (options())
        answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 5:
        import random
        rand = random.randint(1,2)
        guess = int(input("Guess Heads(1) OR Tails(2): "))
        if guess is 1 or guess is 2 and guess is rand:
            print ("You win")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif guess is 1 or guess is 2 and guess is not rand:
            print ("You lose")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        else:
            print ("Error, number must be 1 or 2")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 6:
        fib = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers shall I generate? "))
        x = 1
        y = 1
        print ("Fibonacci sequence up to", fib)
        for i in range (1):
            for i in range (1,fib+1):
                x = y - x
                y = x + y
                if i %10 == 0 and i is not fib:
                    print (x, ", ")
                elif i == fib:
                    print (x)
                else:
                    print (x, ", ", end="")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 7:
        Number = int(input("Factorial of what number do you want? Number must be less than or equal to 20. "))
        if Number > 20:
            print ("Error")
        else:
            Factorial = 1 
            for i in range(1,Number + 1):
                print (i,)
                Factorial = Factorial * i
            print("Factorial of", Number, " is ",Factorial)
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 8:
        num = int(input("Enter multiplication table you want to see: "))
        maximum = int(input("Enter max you want your table to go to: "))
        counter = 0
        print ("The table of", num)
        for i in range (0,maximum):
            counter = i + 1
            print (counter, "*", num, "=", counter*num)
        print ("Done counting...")
        print (" ")
        print (options())
        answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 9:
        import random
        number = int(input("Guess any number 1 to 10? "))
        guess = random.randint(1,10)
        acc = 0
        while guess > 0:
            if guess < number:
                print ("Too High")
                number = int(input("Guess any number 1 to 10? "))
                acc+=1
            elif guess > number:
                print ("Too Low")
                number = int(input("Guess any number 1 to 10? "))
                acc+=1
            elif guess == number:
                acc+=1
                break
        print ("And it only took you", acc, "tries")
        print (" ")
        print (options())
        answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 10:
        import random
        rand = random.randint(1,4)
        print (options2())
        answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 5: "))
        if answer > 5 and answer < 1:
            print ("Sorry, that is not an option")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif answer == 1:
            x=float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
            y=float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
            print (x,"+",y,"=",x+y)
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif answer == 2:
            x=float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
            y=float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
            print (x,"-",y,"=",x-y)
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif answer == 3:
            x=float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
            y=float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
            print (x,"*",y,"=",x*y)
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        elif answer == 4:
            x=float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
            y=float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
            if y == 0:
                print ("Error, denominator cannot be zero")
                print (" ")
                print (options())
                answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
            else:
                print (x,"/",y,"=",x/y)
        elif answer == 5:
            x=float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
            y=float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
            if rand == 1:
                print (x,"+",y,"=",x+y)
                print (" ")
                print (options())
                answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
            elif rand == 2:
                print (x,"-",y,"=",x-y)
                print (" ")
                print (options())
                answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
            elif rand == 3:
                print (x,"*",y,"=",x*y)
                print (" ")
                print (options())
                answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
            elif rand == 4:
                print (x,"/",y,"=",x/y)
                print (" ")
                print (options())
                answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
        else:
            print ("Error, must choose from the aforementioned selections")
            print (" ")
            print (options())
            answer = int(input("Enter a choice from 1 through 11: "))
    elif answer == 11:
        break
print ("You have exited")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/python-function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Comment: Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Don't print the return values of functions that don't return anything meaningful.

Comment: Simply call `options()` instead of `print (options())`.

Comment: I tried replacing print statements with return and it didn't work.

Comment: Let me try that right now.

Comment: Wow thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing return values from functions, as @Patrick Haugh indicates. For example, line 82:

```
print (options())
```

runs the function `options()`, which prints out the alternatives, and then prints the return value from `options()`, which is `None` as you don't specify any return value. Instead code line 82 as:

```
options()
```

You need to correct this on a lot of places, and then for other functions as well, e.g. `Celsius()` etc.