# Pyspark UDF column on Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a new column on a dataframe based on the values of some columns. It's returning null in all cases. Anyone know what's going wrong with this simple example?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,1]],columns = ['Foo','Bar','Baz'])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

def get_profile():
    if 'Foo'==1:
        return 'Foo'
    elif 'Bar' == 1:
        return 'Bar'
    elif 'Baz' ==1 :
        return 'Baz'

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('get_profile', lit(get_profile()))
spark_df.show()

   Foo  Bar  Baz get_profile
    0    1    0        None
    1    0    0        None
    1    1    1        None
```

I would expect that the get_profile column would be filled out for all rows.

I also tried this:

```
spark_udf = udf(get_profile,StringType())

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('get_profile', spark_udf())
print(spark_df.toPandas())
```

to the same effect.

Comment: You are comparing strings with numbers. `'Foo' != 1`, same for other conditions. That's why you get none. A UDF expects columns as arguments, while  the `get_profile` has zero arguments.

Comment: go with when/otherwise inbuilt function instead of udf function

Comment: I'd do it like this: `spark_df.withColumn("get_profile", coalesce(*[when(col(c)==1, lit(c)) for c in spark_df.columns]))`

Comment: Thanks - in reality the when/otherwise function isn't practical because there are many more comparisons that take place, this was just a simplified example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `udf` has no knowledge of what the column names are. So it checks each of your conditions in your `if`/`elif` block and all of them evaluate to `False`. Thus the [function will return `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement).

You'd have to rewrite your `udf` to take in the columns you want to check:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def get_profile(foo, bar, baz):
    if foo == 1:
        return 'Foo'
    elif bar == 1:
        return 'Bar'
    elif baz == 1 :
        return 'Baz'

spark_udf = udf(get_profile, StringType())
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('get_profile',spark_udf('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'))
spark_df.show()
#+---+---+---+-----------+
#|Foo|Bar|Baz|get_profile|
#+---+---+---+-----------+
#|  0|  1|  0|        Bar|
#|  1|  0|  0|        Foo|
#|  1|  1|  1|        Foo|
#+---+---+---+-----------+
```

If you have a lot of columns and want to pass them all (in order):

```
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('get_profile', spark_udf(*spark_df.columns))
```

More generally, you can unpack any ordered list of columns:

```
cols_to_pass_to_udf = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('get_profile', spark_udf(*cols_to_pass_to_udf ))
```

But this particular operation does not require a `udf`. I would do it this way:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, when, col, lit

spark_df.withColumn(
    "get_profile",
    coalesce(*[when(col(c)==1, lit(c)) for c in spark_df.columns])
).show()
#+---+---+---+-----------+
#|Foo|Bar|Baz|get_profile|
#+---+---+---+-----------+
#|  0|  1|  0|        Bar|
#|  1|  0|  0|        Foo|
#|  1|  1|  1|        Foo|
#+---+---+---+-----------+
```

This works because `pyspark.sql.functions.when()` will return `null` by default if the condition evaluates to `False` and no `otherwise` is specified. Then the list comprehension of `pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce` will return the first non-null column.

Note this is equivalent to the `udf` ONLY if the order of the columns is the same as the sequence that's evaluated in the `get_profile` function. To be more explicit, you should do:

```
spark_df.withColumn(
    "get_profile",
    coalesce(*[when(col(c)==1, lit(c)) for c in ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
).show()
```

Comment: Got it - much appreciated. So this is a simplified version of the actual function. ln reality, there are a lot more columns/conditions for assigning values, and the nested when structure wouldn't be practical.. Is there a way to feed all columns into the UDF as an argument?

Comment: @flyingmeatball you can also do `spark_udf(*spark_df.columns)`, but you have to make sure that the order of the columns is the same as the order of the arguments to your udf.

Comment: Also even if it's complicated, using a nested `when` is likely [faster than using a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance/38297050#38297050).

Comment: Understood - it's more a readability/ability to program. I'm willing to trade a little speed for being able to certify I'm doing the calculations correctly.