# Inserting function with for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

```
def greeter(name):
    print('Hey %s, I was going to call you 
          yesterday.'%name)

    print('Damn %s, you grew so much since HS.'%name)

    print('It was nice to see you %s!\n'%name)
```

The function is meant to grab a name and insert it in these greetings.

Input:

```
    friends = ['kevin','Darwin','Erica']

        for friend in friends:
         print(greeter(friend))
```

Ouput:

Hey kevin, I was going to call you yesterday.
Damn kevin, you grew so much since HS.
It was nice to see you kevin!

None

Hey Darwin, I was going to call you yesterday.
Damn Darwin, you grew so much since HS.
It was nice to see you Darwin!

None

Hey Erica, I was going to call you yesterday.
Damn Erica, you grew so much since HS.
It was nice to see you Erica!

None

Question: Why is it that every time the function is executed on a friend in the for loop afterwards 'None' pops up?

Comment: `greeter` does not return a value, so `print(greeter(...))` has nothing to print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Comment: Because you print the returned value of the function, which is by default a `None` value (unless specified)

Answer (score 5):

In the `for` loop, you're printing the return value of the `greeter` function. It doesn't return anything, so `None` is displayed. You can change your loop to just call the function, since `greeter` prints all the output itself.

```
for friend in friends:
    greeter(friend)
```