# How to return a complete for Loop in a function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return, nonetype

I'm trying to run a `For loop` in a function but when I call the function only the first value is returned.

I've tried ending the loop with a `print` instead of a `return`, which gets the correct result (It prints every value in the loop) but means a `none` is added to the answer as there is now a double print.

PLEASE NOTE: In these examples one could one could just print "value" directly but I want to be able to run through a for loop, to add complexity later.

The function ending in `return` only prints out the **first value** of the `For loop``:

```
def thing():  
   value = ( 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 )
   for x in value:
    return x

print(thing())
# 1
```

This function uses `print` and gives the **correct** result except with a `none` added due to the double print.

```
def thing1():
   value = ( 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 )
   for x in value:
     print(x)

print(thing1())

>>>  OutPut:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
None
```

How exactly can I get the second result(the full printed loop of all values) whilst removing the "None"?

Comment: `return` exits from the function. If you want to return the full sequence, then just `return value` - there's no need for a loop.

Comment: The `None` you see isn't printed by the `thing1()` function. Your `thing1()` prints exactly what you want. The `None` is probably from an other display something else after in the code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond this is true but I'd like it to run through the loop (ie to be able add more complexity like an if statement)

Comment: @AlexandreB. If it wasn't a function that would be the case. This can be explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement

Comment: @X-cessivePupil Thank you for the link !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `return` is run, the function stops evaluating. If you'd like to return everything in a for loop, return a list of its outputs:

```
ret_vals = []
for x in value:
    ret_vals.append(x)

return(ret_vals)
```

You can print them on new lines like you specified like so:

```
out = func()
for x in out:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[generators](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ydxknp2e)** to return the sequence.

The generator follows the same syntax as a function but, instead of writing `return`, we write `yield` whenever it needs to return something.

```
def thing():  
   value = ( 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 )
   for x in value:
    yield x

res = thing()
for i in res:
  print(i, end=' ')
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```