# Write a function named get_numbers() that returns a list of integers

Tags: python

When I try to run module the output shows "None". What can I change for my function. 
Like this:
Enter a set of numbers separated by spaces for analysis: 10 2 38 23     38     23     21 23
None

```
import math
def get_numbers():
        numbers_string = input("Enter a set of numbers separated by spaces for analysis: ")
        numbers = numbers_string.split()
        for index in range(len(numbers)):
                numbers[index] = int(numbers[index])                
        numbers.sort()
print(get_numbers())
```

output:
Enter a set of numbers separated by spaces for analysis: 10 2 38 23

```
    38     23     21 23
[10, 2, 38, 23, 38, 23, 21, 23]
```

Comment: Just add `return numbers` at the end of the function, to, well, you guessed it, return the numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being returned in your function. Just add `return numbers` at the end of function and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
def get_numbers():
        numbers_string = input("Enter a set of numbers separated by spaces for analysis: ")
        numbers = list(map(int, numbers_string.split()))
        numbers.sort()
        return numbers

print(get_numbers())
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Enter a set of numbers separated by spaces for analysis: 3 6 8 5 4
[3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```