# why do i got 3 times the output none in my code?

Tags: python, return-value

So i am practicing with coding in python. I always use a return statement if i need to return a number so i dont get none. But now when i just want to print out a comment it returns none. Even when i try to use a return statement, it returns a none.

```
def name_tag():
    name = input("Hello, whats your name? : ")
    print(f'Hi {name}, would you like to play a game?')
    print(y_n())

def y_n():
    yes_no = input("Y/N: ")

    if yes_no.lower() == 'y':
        print('Cool, than lets play a game')

    elif yes_no.lower() == 'n':
        print('To bad!')

    else:
        print('Please anwser with [y] or [n]')
        print(y_n())
```

This is the output

```
Hello, whats your name? : jop
Hi jop, would you like to play a game?
Y/N: k
Please anwser with [y] or [n]
Y/N: y
Cool, than lets play a game
None
None
None
```

Comment: functions always return even without a return statement. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) : `Falling off the end of a function also returns None.`

Comment: Related: [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the results of `y_n()`, which is `None` try this:

```
def name_tag():
    name = input("Hello, whats your name? : ")
    print(f'Hi {name}, would you like to play a game?')
    y_n()

def y_n():
    yes_no = input("Y/N: ")

    if yes_no.lower() == 'y':
        print('Cool, than lets play a game')

    elif yes_no.lower() == 'n':
        print('To bad!')

    else:
        print('Please anwser with [y] or [n]')
        y_n()
```

If you want to use `print(y_n())` you could change it so you are returning the strings from `y_n()`:

```
def name_tag():
    name = input("Hello, whats your name? : ")
    print(f'Hi {name}, would you like to play a game?')
    print(y_n())

def y_n():
    yes_no = input("Y/N: ")

    if yes_no.lower() == 'y':
        return 'Cool, than lets play a game'

    elif yes_no.lower() == 'n':
        return 'To bad!'

    else:
        print('Please anwser with [y] or [n]')
        return y_n()
```

Comment: I tried both, but it still returns one none. Or is there a while loop that keeps asking you Y/N if you do not give a y or n

Comment: It doesn't print `None` for me. are you calling `name_tag()` and how are you running it?

Comment: I copy and pasted it in PyCharm and than runned with te run button. It now returns 1 none and not 3

Comment: You're not running just my code in PyCharm and getting output, because my code doesn't call any of the functions. What are you adding to the file in pycharm? if you have `print(name_tag)()` you will get a `None` printed to your terminal. You should just have `name_tag()` at the end of your file.

Comment: Thank you! that print(name_tag()) was the problem!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(y_n())
```

prints the **return value** of the `y_n` function. That value is implicitly `None` as the function does not return anything.

Comment: is there a better way to return the question Y/N if someone does not give a y or n answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code outputs `None` because you call `print(y_n())` which prints the return value of the `y_n()` function which is `None`. What you should do is call the function without using `print()` because the output value is already being printed inside the function.