# Changing Characters in sentence Python whithout library

Tags: python, string, uppercase, lowercase

In my sentence i want :

- replace every # by *
- skip every ?
- if the ascii value of a char is pair so i am transforming into LowerCase + Shift Value ( input user)
- if the ascii value of a char is impair so i am transforming into UpperCase + Shift Value ( input user)
  Its tell me

> line 19, in replace
>       new = ord(lower(c)) + (shift % 26)
>   TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but NoneType found

```
    def lower(c):
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        c = chr(ord(c) + (ord('a') - ord('A')))


def upper(c):
    if 'a' <= 'c' <= 'z':
        c =  chr(ord(c) - (ord('a') - ord('A')))


def replace(text):
    new_text = ''
    for c in text:
        if c == '#':
            new_text += '*'
        elif c == '?':
            continue
        elif ord(c) % 2 == 0:
            new = ord(lower(c)) + (shift % 26)
            if new > ord('z'):
                new = (ord('a') + (new - ord('z')))
            new_text += chr(new)

        elif ord(c) % 2 != 0:
            new = ord(upper(c)) + (shift % 26)
            if new_text > 'Z':
                new_text = chr('Z' + (new_text - 'Z'))
            new_text += chr(new)

    return new_text


sentence = (input("Please enter a sentence to encrypt:\n"))
shift = int(input("Please enter the size of the shift:\n"))
sentence = replace(sentence)
```

Comment: `c` isn't between `A` and `Z` so your `lower` function does not return anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Comment: There is also a typo in your `upper` function so that won't work as you expect either

Comment: How should i write my Upper/Lower function so ?

Comment: You need to decide what you expect to happen when your if statement isn't entered, see the duplicate.

Comment: @Sayse I change so the functio change directly the value of the char but does not seem to help :/