# How to get more than one input from a single input() function in Python?

Tags: python, function, input, arguments

I've learnt that using * before a custom function argument, I can pass more than one or uncertain amount of data as the argument. For adding numbers function or something like that I can pass unlimited amount of data when I call the function. But I want to get these numbers from user. As I don't know how many numbers I'm gonna get, I can't declare variable for each of them previously. Now, how can I get many numbers as input and add them together with a custom function? My idea is quite similar to a calculator in real life.

Here is my code. I want to get the numbers as input instead of putting them manually while writing code. I will be grateful if anyone gives me the code about what I was trying to do.

```
def add_number(*args):
    total = 0
    for number in args:
        total += number
    print(total)


add_number(2, 3, 6, 9)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: print(sum(map(float, input("Enter the numbers... ").split())))

Comment: You may use `sum(...)` instead of `add_number(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you need to use a **single** input. In this case we can split our input using the `.split(separator)` method of the string, which returns a list of parts of the given string. `separator` argument is optional: if the user enters the numbers separated by whitespace characters, you don't need to pass this argument, otherwise you need to pass a separator.

```
numbers = input("Enter the numbers... ").split()  # if numbers are separated by any of whitespace characters ("1 2 3 4")
```

```
numbers = input("Enter the numbers... ").split(", ")  # if numbers are separated by a comma and a space ("1, 2, 3, 4")
```

**Note:** I'll suppose your numbers are separated by a whitespace character in the next part of answer.

If we would like to print the `numbers` list, we will get this output:

```
>>> numbers = input("Enter the numbers... ").split()
Enter the numbers... 1 2 3 4
>>> print(numbers)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

As we can see all the items of our list are **strings** (because of the quotation marks: `'1'`, not `1`). If we'll try to concatenate them together we'll get something like this: `'1234'`. But if you want to concatenate them together as numbers, not strings, we'll need to convert them to **int** (for integers) or **float** (for non-integer numbers) type. If we have **one** number, it can be done easily: `int(number)`. But we have got **a list of numbers** and we need to convert every element to `int`.

We can use the `map(func, iterable)` function. It will apply the `func` to every item of `iterable` and return a `map` object - an iterator **(NOT a list!)**:

```
numbers = map(int, numbers)
```

**Note:** if we would like to represent it as a list, we can simply do:

```
numbers = list(map(int, numbers))
```

though it is not necessary here.

And now we can throw all the numbers to your `add_number(*args)` function using the asterisk (*) - [**pack**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) them:

```
add_number(*numbers)
```

**Note:** you can also use `sum` function to add all the numbers from iterable - in this case, you don't need to pack the args, because it gets a single iterable of numbers:

```
sum_ = sum(numbers)
```

And then let's `print` our result:

```
print(sum_)
```

**Important Note:** `sum(iterable)` **returns the sum of the numbers** and prints nothing, while your `add_number(*args)` function **returns None** and prints the number (it is not the same thing!). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement) is a good, detailed explanation.

Here is the whole code what we've written:

```
def add_number(*args):
    total = 0
    for number in args:
        total += number
    print(total)

numbers = input("Enter the numbers... ").split()  # if numbers are separated by any of whitespace characters ("1 2 3 4")
numbers = map(int, numbers)
add_number(*numbers)
```

And here is a one-liner that does the same thing - it uses `sum` function instead of the `add_number` and hence doesn't require anything else in the code:

```
print(sum(map(int, input("Enter the numbers... ").split())))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. It helped me a lot. 

Comment: @HMKhalidMahmud, I was very glad to help you! :)