# Can assertions compare against print statments?

Tags: python, assertion

Can assertions compare against print statements in python like this:

```
def printname(name):
    print(name)

#to not raise an error:
assert printname("Hello") == "Hello"

#to raise an error:
assert printname("Hello") == "notHello"
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but highly relevant: [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement). Also, what if you try `assert print('hello') == None` and see what happens?

Comment: Are you trying to test that it actually printed what was intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, assertions can't do that. If you want to do that try this:

```py
def printname(name):
    print(name)
    return name

#to not raise an error:
assert printname("Hello") == "Hello"

#to raise an error:
assert printname("Hello") == "notHello"
```

This technically doesn't compare it, but its a valid workaround. If you really want to compare them take a look into `StringIO`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mock + stringIO to capture stdout/err:

```
from mock import patch
from StringIO import StringIO

def test_foobar():
    out, err = StringIO(), StringIO()
    with patch.multiple(sys, stdout=out, stderr=err):
         do_stuff()
    assert out.getvalue() == 'foo'
    assert err.getvalue() == 'bar'
```

Also if you are doing this within a test framework, you may be able to do a variety of things.  In particular for pytest:

```
def test_myoutput(capsys):  # or use "capfd" for fd-level
    print("hello")
    sys.stderr.write("world\n")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "hello\n"
    assert captured.err == "world\n"
    print("next")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "next\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The function printname doesn't have an explicit return statement, so it return the value . So the assert compares None against a string and of course it raise an assertion error.