# I get a 'none' at the bottom of the result when I run my code

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Hi I am a beginner in python and I am currently using Automate the boring stuff with python. This is my second book learning python. I practiced doing this code (transferring items in list to a dictionary) my code worked the way I wanted it to work but there is a 'none' at the bottom. Can someone enlighten my tiny brain on how to fix this please?

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):

    for i in addedItems:
        if i == 'gold coin':
            inventory['gold coin'] += 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
            inventory[i] += 1

    print('Inventory:')
    total_item = 0

    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        total_item += v

    print('\nTotal number of items: ' + str(total_item))


inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
print(addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot))
```

This is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP1Ol.png

Comment: `addToInventory()` contains no return-statement, so when it is complete it returns `None` which is the default return value. You print the result of that function call so you print `None`. Just called the function without enclosing it in `print()` and you'll no longer get the undesired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Comment: In other words, change `print(addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot))` to `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)`

Comment: ohh thats it thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not returning anything from addToInventory function. If you return total_item then it won't print **None**. After updating your code, it would look something like this:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):

    for i in addedItems:
        if i == 'gold coin':
            inventory['gold coin'] += 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
            inventory[i] += 1
    
    print('Inventory:')
    total_item = 0
    
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        total_item += v
    
    print('\nTotal number of items: ' + str(total_item))
    return total_item
```

Comment: i tried this but the 'none' word at the result became '48'

Comment: Because that is what we are returning. We are returning the total items.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your function is sound. It returns `None` because unlike some other languages, Python functions return `None` by default, unless you tell it to explicitly return something.
For example:

```
def func_A():
    x=5

def func_B():
    x=5
    return x

print(func_A())   # prints "None"
print(func_B())   # prints 5
```

Therefore, try this instead:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):

    for i in addedItems:
        if i == 'gold coin':
            inventory['gold coin'] += 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
            inventory[i] += 1

    print('Inventory:')
    total_item = 0

    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        total_item += v

    print('\nTotal number of items: ' + str(total_item))
    return total_item # this is key
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions always return something. If you use the `return` keyword explicitly, then the function will return that value. If you don't use the `return` keyword, then the function will return `None` by default.

This is what is happening in your `addToInventory` function - it returns `None`. So when you do `print(addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot))` at the end of your script, you are printing the `None` that the function returns. The part that prints the total number of items happens before that, inside the `addToInventory` function itself.

To return the total number of items from the function and print that, you might do something like this:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):

    for i in addedItems:
        if i == 'gold coin':
            inventory['gold coin'] += 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
            inventory[i] += 1

    print('Inventory:')
    total_items = 0

    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        total_items += v

    return total_items


inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
print('\nTotal number of items: ' + str(addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)))
```