# how to get around "none" printing when using a function

Tags: python, loops, output

So I wrote this fx to make me "multiplication tables", I finally got everything right including the formating. Except the that when I call my fx it prints none after the table. Now I know you can by pass that using return but I can't use return here (am I correct because returning more than one variable from an fx makes a tuple???? I couldn't "unpack" this tuple. Anyways here how do I stop the none from printing?

```
[IN]:



def multitables(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(end="\n")  
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            print (j, i, i*j, end="\t") 

print(multitables(3))

[OUT]: 
1 1 1   2 1 2   3 1 3   
1 2 2   2 2 4   3 2 6   
1 3 3   2 3 6   3 3 9   None
```

My table has to be formatted this way. I tried using this format thing I found the last line of my code would change to this.

```
print ("{0} {1} {2}".format(j, i, i*j),
```

But it doesn't do anything. Any input would be great!

Thanks.

Rache;

Comment: do not use `print(multitables(3))` use `multitables(3)` this is because `multitables` returns `None`

Comment: You can find a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `None` at the end is coming from `print`-ing the result of `multitables` itself (since it has no `return`, the return value is `None`)

To remove the `None`, don't `print` the result of the call:

```
multitables(3)
```

Should give:

```
1 1 1   2 1 2   3 1 3   
1 2 2   2 2 4   3 2 6   
1 3 3   2 3 6   3 3 9
```