# Printing a void function executes function

Tags: python

I wrote a function that takes in a number and prints its square. When I used the print function and passed the function-with 2 as its input- as the print function's argument, the output was 4 and 'None'.

'None' I can understand, but why did Python execute the function and output 4 here? I had only used a print statement.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't include the code you're having issues with?

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me; I've been trying for a long time and I can't get it formatted right. It's the simple, obvious code for what I've  described, nothing more.

Comment: `print(foo(5))` will execute `foo(5)` and then print the returned result.

Comment: Just paste your code into your question, highlight it and press ctrl + k

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Comment: `why did Python execute the function and output 4 here` Because _that's what you told it to do._ If you had posted your code, it would be a lot easier to explain this.

Comment: @Sayse: I've been doing exactly that on both PC and Android for hours now.

Comment: Then you'd be better off posting the unformatted code, your question is incomplete without it

Comment: @JohnD: I know how 'None' got printed, I want to know how the function executed and printed the value 4 in the first place.

Comment: Because you put `square(2)`, which _is a function call_, as an argument to `print()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have something like this:

```py
>>> def square(n):
...   print(n ** 2)
... 
>>> print(square(2))
4
None
```

You don't have a return statement so python returns `None`. Try this instead:

```py
>>> def square(n):
...   return n ** 2
... 
>>> print(square(2))
4
```

The reason why the `4` got printed is becuase **you called** `square()`. Calling square had the side-effect of printing the square since that's what it's definition body says to do.

Comment: "'None' I can understand, but why did Python execute the function and output 4 here?" - Your answer is the opposite of what the op is asking about. Its better to wait for enough details than to presume

Comment: I understood why Python gave me 'None'; i wanted to know why it still executed the square() function when all I had done was write a print statement. Your code is exactly what I meant, btw.

Comment: @Sayse it was pretty clear what he meant, as he said above my code is exactly what he meant. I will edit it with why it still executed the function so you can remove the downvote :)

Comment: So even if a function is called inside of a print statement, it still executes as normal?

Comment: yep since you are calling it. If you wanted to just print the mem address without calling it, you can do `print(square)` which will give something like `<function square at 0x105af8310>`

Comment: That's what I needed to know, thanks. can you elaborate on the memory address thing?

Comment: To _call_ a function, you write its name and put `()` after, like so: `square(5)`.  However if you leave off the parentheses, then you have the _function object_, which is fundamentally just an object like any other, and can be printed just like any other object.  The default representation for function objects is to display the function name and memory address.

Answer (score 0):

By placing the `()` next to the function, you called it.  So it got executed.  The print statement around it caused the return value `None` to be printed, while inside it printed the square.

If you don't want to call the function, remove the `()` (and any parameters).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just this: do functions execute even when they're called from inside print statements?

Comment: @HarryHolmes : Yes, Python is made in a way that you can use the return statements from functions to print something, like `print(getUserId("this is my userName"))`  It looks better than: `userId=getUserId("this is my username"); print(userId)`, so they made it that way.