# Could anybody tell me why is it returning None value at end other than the required numbers?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def collatz(a):
    if a==1:
        return a
    elif a%2==0:
        print(a//2)
        collatz(a//2)
    else:
        print(a*3+1)
        collatz(a*3+1)

a = int(input("Enter no. "))
print(collatz(a))
```

Comment: your `elif` and `else` block aren't returning anything. you need to add return while calling `return collatz(...)`

Comment: if you don't `return` your function will return `None`

Comment: Instead of `print(collatz(a))` try just `collatz(a)` at the end

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1):

First see [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Then your method has nothing to return, because the purpose is to see the path of values and the stop value is always `1`

```
def collatz(a):
    print(a)
    if a == 1:
        return             # just the stop case
    elif a % 2 == 0:
        collatz(a // 2)
    else:
        collatz(a * 3 + 1)
```

So call it without a print, you don't expect anything to be returned

```
a = int(input("Enter value:"))
collatz(a)
```

---

You could even combine in

```
def collatz(a):
    print(a)
    if a % 2 == 0:
        collatz(a // 2)
    elif a > 1:
        collatz(a * 3 + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the functions directly:

```
def collatz(a):
    if int(a)==1:
        return a
    elif a%2==0:
        print(a//2)
        return collatz(a//2)
    else:
        print(a*3+1)
        return collatz(a*3+1)
```