# What is the purpose of "return" in function? To whom "return" return's the value?

Tags: python, function, loops, recursion, return

Some say that `return` returns the value to the function. While learning DSA some referred, (in recursion) when "return" is used or when the base case hits, values are printed down the stack.

Example:

```py
def print_sum(i, n, sum):
    if i==n:
        sum += n
        print(sum)
        return sum
    else:
        sum += i
        print_sum(i+1,n,sum)
    # print(i)

print(print_sum(1,5,0))
```

If `return` is returning the value to the function, why does `print(print_sum(1,5,0))` show `None` as the output. This should provide "sum" i.e `15` as output as I have returned sum.

Comment: [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7053652/15497888) you only `return` in one of the branches of your function.

Comment: "*if "return" is returning the value to the function, why does "print(print_sum(1,5,0))" provides None as output*" [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17778372)

Comment: `return` returns the value to the caller of the function.  Your function only returns the value at the very bottom of the stack (when `i == n` and where the caller is another `print_sum` call).  The top of the stack (where you call `print`) calls `print_sum` without returning the value, so it defaults to returning `None`, which is then printed.  If you changed the `print_sum(i;+1, n, sum)` line to `return print_sum(i+1, n, sum)` then the return value would get propagated all the way up the stack.

Comment: As @Samwise says: `return` returns the value to the caller of the function. In your case, the function is sometimes its own caller. That's what makes it recursive. In order to `return` the (intermediate values and) final value to the ultimate caller you need `return print_sum(i+1,n,sum)`. It is a failing of teachers to shortchange students by saying "`return` returns a value", without saying where that value goes.

Comment: Thanks samwise. Your reply has better understanding than the vdo lectures. Thanks quamrana for your re-contribution.