# Python returns None to input

Tags: python

Hey so I’m writing a text-adventure game in python and made a typingprint function to make the text look like it was typed out. But when I try to use this function with inputs it will reply with None.

```
import random
import time
import console
import sound
import sys


def typingPrint(text):
    for character in text:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

console.set_color()

typingPrint('Hello! My name is Sawyer and I will be your guide 
throughout this game. Heres a helpful hint, every time you enter
room you will have to battle a enemy.')

time.sleep(3)

player_name = input(typingPrint('\nBefore we begin why don\'t  
you tell me your name: '))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need `typingPrint(input("\nBefore we begin why dont you tell me your name: '))`. Also don't assign this to a variable. Your function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Switch the places of `typingPrint` and `input`.

Comment: What is your objective? Do you want the `input` prompt to appear as being typed in real time? Or do you want the output of the `typingPrint` function to be passed as `input`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your function doesn't `return` anything so there is no text in the input prompt. To solve it, you will need to first call your function, then the input -

```
typingPrint('Hello! My name is Sawyer and I will be your guide throughout this game. Heres a helpful hint every time you enter a room you will have to battle a enemy.')
time.sleep(3)
typingPrint('\nBefore we begin why dont you tell me your name: ')
player_name = input()
```

Comment: You could also change `typingPrint` to `return text` at the end, which would allow it to be chained with other statements.

Comment: @Samwise, no in this case that wouldn't make sense. Then it would print the text twice.