# Why do I get None in the output of this function?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, anagram

I was asked to write a function to arrange a given number to get its maximum number.
The output is correct, but I keep getting `None` beside the rearranged number.
Obs: I don't want a new code. I want this one fixed.

```
def max(s):
    l=[]
    for i in str(s):
        l.append(int(i))
    l.sort()
    l.reverse()
    for i in l:
        print(i,end="")

print(max(812309))
```

Comment: How could you possibly get anything *other* than None as the result of this function?  It contains no `return` statement!

Comment: Output aside, this is a really inefficient way to get the maximum value of a list. Sorting takes O(n lg n), while you only need O(n) time to find a maximum. Just iterate over the digits, check if each is greater than the largest digit found so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the output of my function printing out "None"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Answer (score 1):

It prints `None` because the function does not return anything. So instead just don't print the function output and simply call the function like so:

```
def max(s):
    l=[]
    for i in str(s):
        l.append(int(i))
    l.sort()
    l.reverse()
    for i in l:
        print(i,end="")

max(812309)
```

Comment: This will give the intended print out.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have set up the call to your method/function, you are actually calling `print` *on* the method itself i.e. `print(max(812309)).`

This is incorrect, as the way the compiler reads it is that it will attempt to print the method rather than a given input (which is the usual practice -- e.g. a string, int, etc).
EDIT: As @kindall mentioned, my explanation here is inaccurate. The compiler is not printing the method, but rather the return value of the method (in this case, no value is being returned so `None` is printed. My mistake!)

Judging by your description, you want to print out your numbers after having been sorted from your method. However, your method is ALREADY doing the printing; so just call the method by itself and you'll get your expected result.

Comment: This explanation is incorrect. You're not printing the function, you're printing the result of the function. Which is `None` because the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Instead of keeping the inaccurate explanation and having an "EDIT:" block, just remove the inaccurate explanation because it's not useful to keep it here (especially since it's the 1st thing people read).

Answer (score 0):

Because you doesn't implement a return statement inside your function.

So the python interpreter adds a "return None" at the end of your function.

Reference read [this article](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#understanding-the-python-return-statement)