# unction return values only working once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The code below runs and prints out the values returned from the two functions `test_value(address)` and `checkRepeatCount(address)` when i try to add the two value returned i `None` as the result. Anyway to fix this?

```
def check(address):
   
   ## define point variables
    pass_invalid_char = test_value(address)
    pass_repeat_count = checkRepeatCount(address)

    if pass_invalid_char == False:
        return print("Invalid character")
    else:
        pass
    
   total = pass_invalid_char+pass_repeat_count
   print(total)



check("hello")
```

Function 1 test_value

```
def test_value(value):
    return print(30)
```

Function 2 checkRepeatCount

```
def checkRepeatCount(value):
    return print(20)
```

Thats how im returning the function values

Comment: You code is not reproducible, what are `test_value` and `checkRepeatCount`?

Comment: The function `print()` always returns `None`, and also any function with no explicit return will return `None`. So your function is always returning `None`. Did you mean to do `return total` insead of `print(total)`?

Comment: In short, your function does not return anything. It merely prints and exits. You must have a `return` line for it to pass something back to the caller. (Note that you can have it `print(total)` and `return total` if you want both behaviors)

Comment: both functions return a number, im trying to get the total number of the two added together. When i run the two individually they work, they are being imported from their own file

Comment: I was returning a print statement with the value thank you

Comment: you should add the entire code including that of the mentioned functions so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jNevil could you post something so i can close this question your answer got me to the solution

Comment: @Zaynekomichi ok, but why not edit this question and make it better instead?

Comment: Let me do that!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the output of my function printing out "None"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/why-is-the-output-of-my-function-printing-out-none)

Comment: not really let me post what my error was

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both functions was returning a print statement with value

```
def test_value(value):
    return print(30)
```

I was supposed just to return the number on its own like so

```
def test_value(value):
    return 30
```