# Why is there showing a 'None' in the Output after "world"?

Tags: python, printing, nonetype

```
print("hello", print("world"))
```

[why there is a none after the word "hello"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPwuv.png)

Comment: Why, did you print in print ?

Comment: Because you are printing the return value of `print()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "None" printed after my function's output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/why-is-none-printed-after-my-functions-output)

Comment: Are you not also curious why `world` is output before `hello`?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to do

`print("hello", "world")`

Expressions (like `print(something)`) are evaluated from the inside-out. That lets you do stuff like

```
print(1 + 2)
# prints 3
```

The return value of `print` is `None`. So when you run `print("hello", print("world"))`, first `"world"` is printed, and then you essentially have `print("hello", None)`.

Answer (score -1):

Because print itself does not return anything, i.e. it returns `None`.
Your nested print statements are evaluated from the inside out, that is why `world` prints first and then `hello` + the return value of `print` = `None`