# Input function is adding None

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the input function but every time, without fail, the word `"None"` appears at the end of my question/string (well running), it's capitalized just like that but has no overall effect on the code, it just ruins the project I'm working on.

Here's my code:

```
import time
import sys
def dp(s):
    for c in s:
        if c != " ":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.22)
        elif c == " ":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0)

name = input(dp("Hello, whats your name? "))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "None" printed after my function's output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/why-is-none-printed-after-my-functions-output)

Answer (score 2):

Every function in python will return something, and if that something isn't defined it will be `None` (you can also explicitly `return None` in a function). So, your `dp()` function returns `None`, and so you are effectively calling `input(None)`, which gives the same prompt of `None`.

Instead, try putting in `input()` call within the function itself.

```py
def dp(s):
    for c in s:
        if c != " ":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.22)
        elif c == " ":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0)
    return input()

name = dp("Hello, whats your name? ")
```