# The data from the while loop doesn't append to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, append

I wanted to make a program that adds the data from a while loop to a list, and computes the data. However, when I use .append, It returns nothing.

```
structure = input("Equation: ")
print("RANGE")
upper_lim = int(input("Upper limit: "))
value_i = int(input("The value of 'i': "))
nth = [""]
substitution = [""]

while value_i <= upper_lim and "i" in structure and "+" not in structure:
    substitution = print(structure.replace("i", "(" + str(value_i) + ")"))
    value_i += 1 
    nth.append(substitution)


while value_i <= upper_lim and "i" in structure:
    substitution = print(structure.replace("i", "(" + str(value_i) + ")"))
    value_i += 1
    nth.append(substitution)
    
print(nth)
```

It came out as:

```
   ['', None, None, None]
```

instead of something like:

```
   [numbers,numbers,numbersr]
```

Comment: What's `value_i` and `structure`? Please edit your post to be minimal, complete, and reproducible

Comment: `print` returns always `None`.

Comment: @Drew0429: please _edit_ your post to be minimal, complete, and reproducible

Comment: Please edit your post to include the inputs you supplied as well as the expected and observed outputs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "None" printed after my function's output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/why-is-none-printed-after-my-functions-output)

Comment: @JorgeLuis, it doesn't. It stops at the very first loop.

Comment: With which input?

Answer (score 0):

```
obj={"one":"1","two":"2"}
while i<5:
    substitution = print(obj) #obj will get printed
    i += 1 
    print("subs = ",substitution) #substitution will have None, since print from the above line will return None
    nth.append(substitution)
```

Print() displays the item but return None which gets saved in substitution variable

Comment: So why don't you also show the correct version?

Comment: Is there a way to gather the data from the substitution variable to a list?

Comment: So if code inside `print()` is displaying correct output, then we can just remove the print and rest code will remain the same, so substitution variable will have the desired result and will get appended in the list?

Comment: Why do you think I want to print the output? Because I need it. If "None" is the printed result of the variable, Do you think the result is getting appended in the list?