# What are these "none" at the bottom of my output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Brand new to python. When using the map function in python, i get a series of the word "none" as an output when i run my function. ive added screenshot below.

Code

```
def rawGradeToLetter(grade):
   if grade >= 90:
      print ("A")
   elif grade < 90 and grade >= 80:
      print ("B")
   elif grade < 80 and grade >= 70:
      print ("C")
   elif grade < 70 and grade >= 60:
      print ("D")
   elif grade < 60:
      print ("F")

def convertRawsToLetters(myList):
   return list(map(rawGradeToLetter, myList))
```

Example run:

```
>>> convertRawsToLetters([90,80,70])
A
B
C
[None, None, None]
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the word list before the map function, but if I remove that all I get is the address of the map like "map object at 0x8g9b7ea51950".

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-than-printing-it

Comment: In addition to the problem of needing to return rather than print, note that `map` isn't used very often in Python since it can almost always be replaced by a more readable list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

You need to *return* the grades, not *print* them. Printing the grades displays them on screen instead of giving a value back to the caller.

```
def rawGradeToLetter(grade):
   if grade >= 90:
      return "A"
   elif grade < 90 and grade >= 80:
      return "B"
   elif grade < 80 and grade >= 70:
      return "C"
   elif grade < 70 and grade >= 60:
      return "D"
   elif grade < 60:
      return "F"
```

Without a `return` statement your function implicitly returns `None`, which explains why you're seeing `[None, None, None]` in your output.

Comment: Note: The final `elif` could just be made an `else`, with the only difference in behavior occurring for "weirdo" objects like `float('nan')` which return `False` for all comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you aren't returning anything on your map function, so it doesn't work correctly. You can try this, so the instead of being mapped to `None`, it will be mapped to the results:

```
def rawGradeToLetter(grade):
    if grade >= 90:
        print ("A")
        return "A"
    elif grade < 90 and grade >= 80:
        print ("B")
        return "B"
    elif grade < 80 and grade >= 70:
        print ("C")
        return "C"
    elif grade < 70 and grade >= 60:
        print ("D")
        return "D"
    elif grade < 60:
        print ("F")
        return "F"

def convertRawsToLetters(myList):
   return list(map(rawGradeToLetter, myList))
```

It is, if you want to maintain the prints, if not, you can remove them.

Answer (score -1):

```
def rawGradeToLetter(grade):
    if grade >= 90:
        print ("A")
    elif grade < 90 and grade >= 80:
        print ("B")
    elif grade < 80 and grade >= 70:
        print ("C")
    elif grade < 70 and grade >= 60:
        print ("D")
    elif grade < 60:
        print ("F")


def convertRawsToLetters(myList):
    for grade in myList:
        rawGradeToLetter(grade)
```

I think you are over complicating it by using map() if all you want to do is print the grades.

Comment: @wpercy Yeah, I was looking at someone else's code for the rawGradeToLetter function. The OP doesn't actually need a list though and I think that's what you're talking about. OP just wants to print.