# 'Type Error: Nonetype object is not iterable' while comparing lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two functions, `Dte()` which pulls `dates` from the database and contains some missing dates and `generate_dates()` which prints all dates in a range. I tried to compare both the lists and store zero in place of missing values in a third list (`mylist2`).

This is my code:

```
def dte(): 
    for row in ddt: 
        date = (' '.join(map(str,row))) 
        print(date)      
    #dte()

def generate_dates(start_date, end_date):
    td = datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        print current_date
        current_date += td

    start_date = datetime.date(2017, 07, 26)
    end_date = datetime.date(2017,9, 11)
    #generate_dates(start_date, end_date)


    mylist2=[i if i in dte() else 0 for i in generate_dates(start_date, 
    end_date)]
    print(mylist2)
```

However, when I execute the code, I get a `TypeError`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python is very picky about indentation. Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it especially the second answer.

Answer (score 2):

You say `if i in dte()`. This means that you iterate over `dte()` to see if `i` is in it. However `dte()` doesn't return anything, therefore it returns `None`. So what is actually there is `if i in None`, and you can't iterate a `None`.

Comment: Should I return date in the dte()?

Comment: Yes, note that you also have the same problem for `generate_dates`

Comment: I returned both date and current_date, but now its showing another error saying datetime.date object is not iterable

Comment: In order to be able to iterate you need some sort of list. I assume your functions don't return lists now. So `dte()` should return a list of the dates in the database, and `generate_dates` should return a list of all the generated dates.

Comment: How do i roll them back to a list?

Comment: @RadixAlmight Can you tell me how `row` looks like in `dte()`?