# Python - How to calculate lists within lists, with arithmetic between them

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this 'equation' using recursion (without regex), but for some reason it keeps resetting the def `par(string)` back after `action(calc)` has finished its first loop, instead of continuing from where it (i) was before the first par function started (the i local variable resets to 40 after the calc loop).

my code prints out

```
1
1
1
```

if I do

```
print par(equation)
```

it prints out

```
1
```

there is no real reason to print inside the function, but I was wondering if you guys could help me out here, im using Python 2.7

here is my code:

```
equation = "[[[3+4] + [5*6]] + [5/7] / [[3+2] + [4/2]] * [2-1]]"
equation = equation.replace(" ", "")

def action(calc):
  x = int(calc[0])
  y = int(calc[2])
  if calc[1] == "+":
      result = x+y       
  elif calc[1] == "-":
      result = x-y      
  elif calc[1] == "*":
      result = x*y       
  else:
      result = x/y  
  return result

def par(string):
  for i in range(len(string)-1, 0, -1):
    if string[i] == "]":
      result =  par(string[:i])
    elif string[i] != "[":
        calc = string[i-2:i+1]
        result = action(calc)
        return result
    else:
        return result


par(equation)
```

Comment: You'll want to read up on parsing and context-free grammars.

Comment: "I've been trying to solve this 'equation' using recursion" Your solution doesn't use recursion.

Comment: if this is a division, then  you have an extra  bracket somewhere at the beginning. and why do you have this as a string? last thing why you have the square brackets instead of parenthesis?

Comment: @Herc01 Its not a 'real' question, just something someone gave me and told me to solve without regex. like calculating the sum of nested lists.

Comment: A return will force the for loop to break, whereas print won't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it . What is the desired output? A fun way to do this is: `eval(equation.replace('[','(').replace(']',')'))`...
`Out[44]: 37.10204081632653`

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry Thanks alot, helped me a ton.