# Why do we return None in this decorator?

Tags: python, return, return-value, python-decorators

I am reading this code snippet in Python:

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function(*arg,**kwargs):
        print("This line is executed before the original function")
        result = original_function(*arg, **kwargs)
        print("This line is executed after the original function")
        print (result)
        return result #Why do we need to return result from this decorator?
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function
def display_info(name, age):
    print(name, age)

display_info("You", 1)
display_info("Me", 99)
```

The decorated function returns a None, and the code snippet above will produce the same result regardless if we have this line, `return result`.

I am wondering if there is any reason (Pythonic? Future code maintenance?) to return this None.

The code snippet is part of Python tutorial on decorator on YouTube.

Thanks

Comment: Your original function `display_info` returns `None` because it has no return statement. That's nothing to do with decorators. The decorated version returns `result`, which is the return value from the original function, which is `None`. If the same decorator was used to decorate a _different_ function (one that returned something), it would have a different return value.

Comment: @khelwood, thanks I actually made a mistake in my original post. What I meant to ask is: why do we have return result, not print (result).

Comment: You should use `#` for starting in-line comments in python not `//`

Comment: @Mohit, thank you. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorated function will return `None` because the function `display_info` has no return statement therefore it returns void. And the closure inside the `decorator_function` returns and prints the same value as returned by the call to the original function `display_info`(which is untouched by the action of decorator), it is obvious that it will return a `None` value.

**Edit**:

> Why do we need that return statement?

This is completely optional in the case, you are sure that this decorator can only be added to a function that returns void or absolutely nothing, but if it is not the case you need to add a return statement because if you don't add a return statement your original function that has chances to return something will return void.

Comment: thanks I actually made a mistake in my original post. What I meant to ask is: why do we have return result, not print (result)

Comment: @YuZhang Edited my post, see if it helps

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I was thinking on a limited picture. As the decorator function does not know for sure what a decorated function will return, it can be a None or something else; as a good practice, we need to return it.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning `None` because your `display_info()` returns Nothing.

```
result = original_function(*arg, **kwargs)
```

Here result, will get `None`. So when you try to `print(result)` you get None.

I believe you were expecting the tuple `("You", 1)` in your `result`.

Comment: thanks I actually made a mistake in my original post. What I meant to ask is: why do we have return result, not print (result)

Comment: @YuZhang Because you want to return it, not print it? Do you understand [the difference between return and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, emmmmm, it looks my question is still not clear. What I meant to ask if why I would return a None which will make no difference in the outcome of this program; From Mohit's answer, I think he / she answered it: the decorator function may be used to decorate many functions, some of which return None, some of which do not return None. As a precaution / good practice, we return the outcome of the decorated function. Sorry for the confusion.