# How to fix 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int''

Tags: python

I have been working over an hour and can't get my functions to pass the unit test. My code is as follows:

```
def miles_to_laps(x):
  laps = float(x * 4)
  return print('%0.2f' % laps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  user_miles = float(input())
  miles_to_laps(user_miles)
```

The output is correct but when it performs unit tests I'm getting the correct answer but then it is throwing an error after. I tried this on the next lab as well and it is doing the same thing.. see below.

for example if the input is 2.2
I get 8.80

but if the input is miles_to_laps(1.5)
I get

```
6.00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zyLabsUnitTestRunner.py", line 10, in <module>
    passed = test_passed(test_passed_output_file)
  File "/home/runner/local/submission/unit_test_student_code/zyLabsUnitTest.py", line 20, in test_passed
    diff_amount = student_result - 6
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
4: Unit test
```

Comment: It seems the problem's on your side. I'm having no troubles with your script. Else, there's something important in your actual code you missed in the sample

Comment: Hint: what does `print` return? `return print('%0.2f' % laps)`

Comment: `return print('%0.2f' % laps)` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it

Comment: _but if the input is miles_to_laps(1.5) I get ..._ This makes no sense.  You mean the user literally typed `miles_to_laps(1.5)` as their input?  Oh, you're using Python 2.  You want `raw_input()`, not `input()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're returning `None` from your function, but some other code expects you to be `return`ing a number instead.

This line doesn't do what you expect:

```
return print('%0.2f' % laps)
```

This prints out the number of laps (with two decimal places), but then returns the value returned by `print`, which is always `None`. If you want to return the number, you should just do `return laps`, probably. The caller can handle printing, if that's desired. It may be that you want to both print and return the value, in which case you'll want to use separate statements:

```
print('%0.2f' % laps)
return laps
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears the problem is not within the code given, which works perfectly fine by my testing. Maybe it's because whatever function you're trying to use it on does not support a float format

Edit: have just found the problem, you're getting a None value returned from the function, which you cannot subtract from

Fix: return the function into a variable,
and do such code - 
(float(variable)-6)
which gets you what you wanted where it failed previously

Comment: You tried entering `miles_to_laps(1.5)` as the input, as he said?

Comment: Thank you so much! I returned the variable and moved the print statement down.