# all substrings in python through recursion

Tags: python, recursion, substring

```
def lst_substrings(s,ans):
    if len(s) == 0:
        print(ans)
    ch=s[0]
    ros=s[1:]
    
    lst_substrings(ros,ans)
    lst_substrings(ros,ans+ch)

s="binod"
ans=" "
lst_substrings(s,ans)
```

I tried to find **list of sub-strings through recursion in python**. But I get an error message like this-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
File "<string>", line 7, in lst_substrings
  File "<string>", line 7, in lst_substrings
  File "<string>", line 7, in lst_substrings
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "<string>", line 4, in lst_substrings
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This same logic fetches result in cpp. I want to go through this approach. Can someone please help me in modifying the code?

Comment: what's the expected output for input string: "aabc" ?

Comment: Please show us some example inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: When the length of the string is 0, `lst_substrings` should **return** in order to skip `ch=s[0]`.

Comment: Please provide sample outputs for a string. For the function itself, the `base case` and `recursive case` need to be better thought out.

Comment: The exception occurs because `print` does not exit the function, so `s[0]` is still attempted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is the expected return, however the error is caused by the fact that the function never returns, hence adding a return will fix the `IndexError`

**EDIT**  Better to append the results of ans in a separate list as shown below

```
result = []
def lst_substrings(s, ans):
    if len(s) == 0:
        print(ans)
        result.append(ans)
        return
    ch = s[0]
    ros = s[1:]

    lst_substrings(ros, ans)
    lst_substrings(ros, ans + ch) 


s = "binod"
ans = " "
lst_substrings(s, ans)
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should separate rendering (printing) from computing results.  This would make the function much simpler and avoir the need to use side effects on a global list that doesn't belong to the function.

```
# computing (as a generator)
def getSubStrings(S):
    for i in range(1,len(S)): yield S[:i]
    if S: yield from getSubStrings(S[1:])

# rendering (i.e. printing results)        
for ss in getSubStrings(s):print(ss)

b
bi
bin
bino
i
in
ino
n
no
o
```