# Defined function keeps returning None, despite having a print() specified within the return line

Tags: python, function, return

```
import textwrap
def wrap(string, max_width):
    i = textwrap.wrap(string, width=max_width)
    print(i)
    z = print(*i, sep='\n')
    return z

string, max_width = 'ABCFSAODJIUOHFWRQIOJAJ', 4 
result = wrap(string, max_width) 
print(result)
```

I am trying to write a code that separates a string in a list, and then prints out each part of the list as a separate line. It works fine until the last bit, where it still attaches None after running the code. I have tried all sorts of ways, but I cannot seem to force my definition to avoid the `None`.

Comment: what do you want to return? `print` returns `None`

Comment: I want it to stop returning None.

Comment: `z = print(*i, sep='\n')` , this will make `z` always `None` and that's what you are returning

Comment: try `print(print("hi"))` -- you'll understand what's happening i think

Comment: The `print` function *displays* the content, but *returns* `None`.

Comment: Okay you guys helped me out a lot. Understood my idiotic mistake. How can I give points and mark as answered?

Comment: Also was worried about posting here, reddit made it seem like I will be burned at a stake for asking such a question. Very nice community afterall!

Comment: Mureinik's answer can be voted on/accepted. And ya, Reddit loves to beat that horse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` returns `None`, and by returning it, your `wrap` function would also return `None`. It seems like you want to join `i` with a newline:

```py
def wrap(string, max_width):
    i = textwrap.wrap(string, width=max_width)
    return '\n'.join(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the function without return , try this instead

````py
def wrap(string, max_width):
   i = textwrap.wrap(string, width=max_width)
   print(i)
   print(*i, sep='\n')
   

string, max_width = 'ABCFSAODJIUOHFWRQIOJAJ', 4 
wrap(string, max_width)  ```
````