# Function that converts a decimal to binary: how to return result instead of printing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary

I need to write a function that converts an integer into binary.
The function definition I have written so far is:

```
def decimalToBinary(number):
    if number > 1:
        decimalToBinary(number//2)
    print(number % 2, end = '')
```

My problem is that:

1. I should return the result instead of printing it, and I am unsure how to do that.
2. I am overall unsure if my code is the best recursive code I could have written.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the digit to a string, and use `return` instead of `print`. Then concatenate it with the recursive call.

```
def decimalToBinary(number):
    if number > 1:
        return decimalToBinary(number//2) + str(number % 2)
    else:
        return str(number % 2)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This really helped

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `count` variable to position the digits

```
def decimalToBinary(number, count = 0):
    if number > 1:
        return ((number%2) * (10**count) + decimalToBinary(number//2, count+1))
    return ((number%2) * (10**count))
```

Also, if you need a non-recursive function you can use something like this

```
def LinealDecimalToBinary(num):
    count = 0
    binNum = 0
    while(num > 0):
        binNum += (num%2) * (10**count)
        num = num//2
        count += 1
    return binNum
```