# Error with eval() function with print function in python

Tags: python, eval

I am trying to run this in Python IDLE:

```
>>> eval(print("123*13"))
```

I get the output correctly, but it comes with a `TypeError`:

```
123*13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(print("123*13"))
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

NOTE:
I do **NOT** want to do `print(eval("123*13"))`.
I want to use `print()` in `eval()` function.
This is NOT for actual implementation, but I got this error while using `eval()` function. I am not asking this for any actual implementation, but curiosity.

Comment: This is equivalent to `eval(None)`

Comment: `print()` prints its argument, it doesn't return it.

Comment: Get rid of the call to `print()` and it will work.

Comment: I think you mean to do `print(eval("123*23"))`

Comment: So, will a function in `eval()` always throw an error if it returns `None`?

Comment: If it returns anything other than a string.

Comment: No, eval expects a string.

Comment: Related: [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750136/4518341)

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` in the first place? Like, what are you actually trying to accomplish? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). Please [edit] to clarify. It'd be best to put it in the form of a question. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: @wjandrea, no, this is exactly where I was stuck, and not like XYproblem

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal, no, I did not mean that. I have updated the question

Comment: @CoolCoder But why? If the string is also in source code, why not just do `print("123*13")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it:

```py
eval('print("123*13")')
```

in eval() src:

```py
evel (__source: str | bytes | CodeType, __globals: Dict[str, Any] | None = ..., __locals: Mapping[str, Any] | None = ...) -> Any
'''Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.

The source may be a string representing a Python expression    
or a code object as returned by compile().
The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
defaulting to the current globals and locals.
If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.'''
...
```

eval help():

```py
eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
    Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.

    The source may be a string representing a Python expression
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

You can see more in [Python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval).

Comment: Thank you @Delta for the answer. It seems that `eval()` function needs only `str` as input, so the `print()` function too must be as a `str`.

Comment: str formats: `'''str''', """str""", 'str', "str", '\'str\'', ...