# function return None after execution of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to split a DNA strand into groups of 3. Everything in the result is intended except for that last "None"

```
def codons(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x), 3):
        result = print(x[i:i + 3])
    return result
```

When using with

```
print(codons('ATGCTCAAGTAGR'))
```

Returns:

```
ATG
CTC
AAG
TAG
R
None
```

Comment: What do you expect the function to do/return?

Comment: This is why I never teach people about `print` too early. If the console is the only output device used in teaching, people tend to miss the difference between printing something and returning something, because ultimately all results are printed anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the result in a list

```
 def codons(x):
        result=[]
        for i in range(0, len(x), 3):
            result.append(x[i:i + 3])
        return result
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything is right, just get rid of the return and the print when calling the function.

```
def codons(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x), 3):
        print(x[i:i + 3])
codons('ATGCTCAAGTAGR')
```