# Can someone help me out with the error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
def fibo(num):

    if num <= 0:
        print("Incoreect input number  should  be more than 0 or equal to 0.")
    
    elif num == 1:
        print("The series is 1.")

    elif num == 2:
        print("The series is 1.")
    
    else:
        return(fibo(num-1) + fibo(num-2))   


def main(): # fibonacci series  
    
    num = int(input("Plz enter the nth  number to genrate fibbonaci numbers "))
    
    print("The Fibonacci series is : ")

    for i in range(num):
        print(fibo(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to check out [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: You need to return something for `num == 1` and `num == 2`  as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `fibo` never returns a numerical value but only print messages if num is 0, 1 or 2.  Hence `fibo(num-1)` and `fibo(num-2)` are NoneType. In addition to your prints you must return a value.

```
def fibo():
    if num <= 0:
        print("Incoreect input number  should  be more than 0 or equal to 0.")

    elif num == 1:
        print("The series is 1.")
        return 1

    elif num == 2:
        print("The series is 1.")
        return 1

    else:
        return(fibo(num-1) + fibo(num-2))
```

Comment: Of course. You can then accept the answer so that the topic is closed.