# unwanted result from a function and if else

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple program using function and if else. Even though there is no errors, my program doesn't give expected result

```
value1 = float(input("Enter your first number:"))
value2 = float(input("Enter your second number:"))
question= input("choose mode:" )
add = True
def nor_cal(num1, num2):
    if question == add:
        total = num1+num2
        print("the total is: ")
        print(total)
    else:
        print("Invalid operator")
result1 = nor_cal(value1, value2)
print(result1)
```

when i run the program, it shows like this:

```
Enter your first number:2
Enter your second number:3
choose mode:add
Invalid operator
None
```

I don't know where i'm wrong please help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: The variable named `question` has the value `"add"` while the variable named `add` has the value `True`. The two variables do not have the same value.

Comment: Use a debugger and check what values it shows for each variable when you hit the line `if question == add`

Comment: There's a difference between `add` and `"add"`. One is a variable (in your case holding a boolean value) and the other is a string (containing the ascii characters 'a,d,d'.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: `question == add` is clearly a typo, and I assume `add = True` was added in to suppress an error message instead of actually thinking about the problem. The problem here that might actually involve conceptual difficulty is the now-linked duplicate. But this question shouldn't have been allowed to stay open in the first place, and certainly shouldn't have been answered.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in the line `if question == add:`, what you're asking the program to do is to compare the variable `question` (which is "add") to the variable `add` (which is True).

You're going to want to use `if question == "add":` instead.